# Clearing an HTML file upload field via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I want to reset a file upload field when the user selects another option.

Is this possible via JavaScript? I'm suspecting that the file upload element is treated differently because it interacts with the user's file system, and maybe it's immutable.

Basically, what I want is something like (pseudo-code):

```
// Choose selecting existing file
$('#select-file').bind('focus', function() {
  // Clear any files currently selected in #upload-file
  $('#upload-file').val(''); 
}) ;

// Choose uploading new one - this works ok
$('#upload-file').bind('focus', function() {
  // Clear any files currently selected in #select-file
  $('#select-file').val(''); 
}) ;
```

NB: **This question and its answers span the period from 2009 to today.** Browsers and approaches have changed in that time, please select your solutions with this in mind :)

Comment: This seems to work and it's 3 lines
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62224815/6730421

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can't set the input value in most browsers, but what you can do is create a new element, copy the attributes from the old element, and swap the two.

Given a form like:

```
<form> 
    <input id="fileInput" name="fileInput" type="file" /> 
</form>
```

The straight DOM way:

```
function clearFileInput(id) 
{ 
    var oldInput = document.getElementById(id); 

    var newInput = document.createElement("input"); 

    newInput.type = "file"; 
    newInput.id = oldInput.id; 
    newInput.name = oldInput.name; 
    newInput.className = oldInput.className; 
    newInput.style.cssText = oldInput.style.cssText; 
    // TODO: copy any other relevant attributes 

    oldInput.parentNode.replaceChild(newInput, oldInput); 
}

clearFileInput("fileInput");
```

Simple DOM way. This may not work in older browsers that don't like file inputs:

```
oldInput.parentNode.replaceChild(oldInput.cloneNode(), oldInput);
```

The jQuery way:

```
$("#fileInput").replaceWith($("#fileInput").val('').clone(true));

// .val('') required for FF compatibility as per @nmit026
```

Resetting the whole form via jQuery: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13351234/1091947

Comment: I tried the other two suggested options above, and the sample code at this link was the one which worked best in the end. I really expected Udo's answer to do it, but it wasn't the go.

I also tried http://gusiev.com/2009/04/clear-upload-file-input-field/

Thanks Chris H

Comment: This is the best I've found so far, but I still have issue with events attached to the field.  Thanks, though!

Comment: Or with jQuery (inside the `change` event handler): `$(this).replaceWith( $(this).clone(true) );`

Comment: You could also wrap it into a form and reset it with jQuery as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13351234/1091947

Comment: Thanks @RyanWheale and @Gigi2m02! -- added these other options to the answer.

Comment: Here's another straight DOM JavaScript way, but with one line like jQuery: oldInput.parentNode.replaceChild(oldInput.cloneNode(), oldInput);

Comment: `$("#CV").replaceWith($("#CV").clone(true));` doesn't work in Firefox but does work in other desktop browsers (haven't tested Safari). `$("#CV").replaceWith($("#CV").val('').clone(true));` seems to work everywhere.

Comment: My solution is much easier and less code than this.
Give it a go: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62224815/6730421

Answer (score 68):

Simply now in 2014 the input element having an id supports the function `val('')`.

For the input -

```
<input type="file" multiple="true" id="File1" name="choose-file" />
```

This js clears the input element -

```
$("#File1").val('');
```

Comment: Does this work in all browsers, or at least the past few versions of the big 4? I've seen some issues where it works in FF but not IE.

Comment: The accepted answer does not work for me, as I use Angular 2, and replacing the element doesn't seem to play nice with Angular. This solution however does work -- so it gets my upvote!

Answer (score 25):

Simple solution:

```
document.getElementById("upload-files").value = "";
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the upload element is protected from direct manipulation in different browsers. However, you could erase the element from the DOM tree and then insert a new one in its place via JavaScript. That would give you the same result.

Something along the lines of:

```
$('#container-element').html('<input id="upload-file" type="file"/>');
```

Comment: very nice - will give this a shot, should be v little hassle to run off a copy of the existing element

Answer (score 5):

The code I ended up using was,

```
clearReviewFileSel: function() {
  var oldInput = document.getElementById('edit-file-upload-review-pdf') ;
  var newInput = document.createElement('input');
  newInput.id    = oldInput.id ;
  newInput.type  = oldInput.type ;
  newInput.name  = oldInput.name ;
  newInput.size  = oldInput.size ;
  newInput.class  = oldInput.class ;
  oldInput.parentNode.replaceChild(newInput, oldInput); 
}
```

Thanks everyone for the suggestions and pointers!

Comment: Thank you for posting the code!  You saved me time and frustration tonight.

Comment: In IE8, "class" is not a valid attribute.  It's "className".

Answer (score 5):

Shorter `version` that works perfect for me that is as follow:

```
document.querySelector('#fileUpload').value = "";
```

Answer (score 4):

They don't get focus events, so you'll have to use a trick like this: only way to clear it is to clear the entire form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#wrapper").bind("mouseover", function() {
            $("form").get(0).reset();
        });
    });
</script>

<form>
<div id="wrapper">
    <input type=file value="" />
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks - yes i had also wondered if there's even a UI method for the user to clear their own file upload field without resetting the entire form

Comment: @ChadGrant good point, thank you. What i did just wrap input with form, reseted form, and unwrap it:)

Answer (score 4):

really like keep things simple like this :)

```
$('input[type=file]').wrap('<form></form>').parent().trigger('reset').children().unwrap('<form></form>');
```

Answer (score 3):

This jQuery worked for me in IE11, Chrome 53, and Firefox 49:

```
cloned = $("#fileInput").clone(true);
cloned.val("");
$("#fileInput").replaceWith(cloned);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this its work fine

```
document.getElementById('fileUpload').parentNode.innerHTML = document.getElementById('fileUpload').parentNode.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 2):

For compatibility when ajax is not available, set .val('') or it will resend the last ajax-uploaded file that is still present in the input.  The following should properly clear the input whilst retaining .on() events:

```
var input = $("input[type='file']");
input.html(input.html()).val('');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the following:

```
<input type="file" id="FileSelect">
```

then just do:

```
$("#FileSelect").val('');
```

to reset or clear last selected file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code...

```
$("input[type=file]").wrap("<div id='fileWrapper'/>");
$("#fileWrapper").append("<div id='duplicateFile'   style='display:none'>"+$("#fileWrapper").html()+"   </div>");
$("#fileWrapper").html($("#duplicateFile").html());
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery tested method working fine in FF & Chrome:

```
$(function(){
    $.clearUploadField = function(idsel){
        $('#your-id input[name="'+idsel+'"]').val("") 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/formdata) api is not so friendly for older browsers and such, but in many cases you are anyways using it (and hopefully [testing for support](https://github.com/New-Bamboo/example-ajax-upload/blob/master/public/index.html)) so this will work fine!

```html
function clearFile(form) {
  // make a copy of your form
  var formData = new FormData(form);
  // reset the form temporarily, your copy is safe!
  form.reset();
  for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
    // if it's not the file, 
    if (pair[0] != "uploadNameAttributeFromForm") {
      // refill form value
      form[pair[0]].value = pair[1];
    }
    
  }
  // make new copy for AJAX submission if you into that...
  formData = new FormData(form);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another one for the pot but you can actually change the type of an input.
If you set the type to text, then back to file, it seems to reset the element.

```
var myFileInput = document.getElementById('myfileinput');
myFileInput.type = "text";
myFileInput.type = "file";
```

It resets.
Tested in Google Chrome, Opera, Edge, IE 11

Answer (score 0):

I faced the issue with ng2-file-upload for angular. if you are looking for the solution on angular by ng2-file-upload, refer below code

**HTML:**

`<input type="file" name="myfile"` **#activeFrameinputFile** `ng2FileSelect [uploader]="frameUploader" (change)="frameUploader.uploadAll()" />`

**component**

`import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';`

`@ViewChild('`**activeFrameinputFile**`')`**InputFrameVariable**`: ElementRef;`

`this.frameUploader.onSuccessItem = (item, response, status, headers) => {`
    `this.`**InputFrameVariable**`.nativeElement.value = '';`
   `};`

Answer (score 0):

I know it is quite old, but testing in the browser:

```
$0.value=null; // when $0 is the file upload element we talking about
```

erased the value and allow me to rechoose THE SAME FILE as before (means it worked!)

Tested in Chrome 81, FF 76, Safari (on iPad mini), 360 browser, Baidu browser, QQ browser, android browser.

## Explanation:

As per my point of view that files selected can be more than 1, you'd better not set the value to a string - the final value sits in $0.files which may be more than 1. The browser need to parse the selected values from "value", so it is an active property. Set it to null, as per my understanding, will cause the browser to parse it to [] empty list in $0.files (this is what happened...)