# How to Encode an <input file> to base64 in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, drupal

I need to save an image into Drupal, through the drupal service/file. For what i understand i need to decode the file into a base64 and send this as a payload for the service/file. How can i get to encode the  in order to do this???? I want to do this in javascript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17502568/2450730 this can help you , contains full example of filereader,canvas resize and save as png

Answer (score 27):

I am the author of [angular-base64-upload](https://github.com/adonespitogo/angular-base64-upload) as mentioned by @GrimurD. This directive works perfectly for this scenario. It parses image(or any other file types) into base64-encoding and attach the file info to a model in your scope.

Sample usage:

```
<input type='file' ng-model='yourModel' base-sixty-four-input>
```

Once you selected a file, `yourModel` will have a value of something like:

```
{
  "filetype": "text/plain",
  "filename": "textfile.txt",
  "base64": "/asdjfo4sa]f57as]fd42sdf354asdf2as35fd4"
}
```

It also has sample code for decoding the base64 file in your server, using PHP or ruby.

Comment: A very elegant extension installable via `bower`.

Comment: great plugin .loving it

Comment: great plugin! this saves my day!

Answer (score 12):

I know it's quite old, but I came here for a solution.

In the end I found out that (if you don't want to use external libraries) loading an image in base 64 is as simple as using javascript [FileReader.readAsDataURL()](http://www.javascripture.com/FileReader#readAsDataURL_Blob)

Hopefully my final code will help others beginners like me. It features:

- Input file with HTML5 `input type='file'` (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22538760/3302886))
- Trigger input from other html elements (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5942858/3302886))
- Check if browser supports `input type='file'` (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11468116/3302886))

It is also on [codepen](http://codepen.io/Karlooie/pen/KdxqZa)

```js
angular.module('starter', [])
  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {}; //init variable
    $scope.click = function() { //default function, to be override if browser supports input type='file'
      $scope.data.alert = "Your browser doesn't support HTML5 input type='File'"
    }

    var fileSelect = document.createElement('input'); //input it's not displayed in html, I want to trigger it form other elements
    fileSelect.type = 'file';

    if (fileSelect.disabled) { //check if browser support input type='file' and stop execution of controller
      return;
    }

    $scope.click = function() { //activate function to begin input file on click
      fileSelect.click();
    }

    fileSelect.onchange = function() { //set callback to action after choosing file
      var f = fileSelect.files[0],
        r = new FileReader();

      r.onloadend = function(e) { //callback after files finish loading
        $scope.data.b64 = e.target.result;
        $scope.$apply();
        console.log($scope.data.b64.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "")); //replace regex if you want to rip off the base 64 "header"

        //here you can send data over your server as desired
      }

      r.readAsDataURL(f); //once defined all callbacks, begin reading the file

    };


  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app='starter' ng-controller='Ctrl'>
  <button ng-click='click()'>click to select and get base64</button>
  <br>BASE 64 data:
  <br>
  <span style='color: red'>{{data.alert}}</span>
  <div style='word-wrap:break-word'>
    {{data.b64}}
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend you to use https://github.com/ninjatronic/angular-base64.

After following instructions for using this library, you can simply call:

```
var imageData=$base64.encode(image);
```

Don't forget to inject in your module:

```
.module('myApp', ['base64'])
```

Comment: That library works well. I used it in conjunction with a php based REST server.

Comment: how can i use it this library with an <input file>

Comment: @Abdrahmn_msi I'm the maintainer - raise an issue on the repo for help https://github.com/ninjatronic/angular-base64/issues

Comment: how can I get from image file

Answer (score 0):

You don't need AngularJs for that. There is a thread here explaining how to do it using Javascript and canvas: [How to convert image into base64 string using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

i found some websites,browser like chrome,ie10..may be support this
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FFileReader

http://www.pjhome.net/web/html5/encodeDataUrl.htm

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and ran into [this repository on github](https://github.com/adonespitogo/angular-base64-upload). Tried it out and it worked perfectly.