# convert image to base64 in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, image-conversion

I have a requirement where user will upload their image and i have to convert it into something and send it to .Net REStful service. I am new to angular js. Could someone please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert image into base64 string using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript)

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549968/how-to-encode-an-input-file-to-base64-in-angularjs

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24880314/625189

> I would recommend you to use
>   https://github.com/ninjatronic/angular-base64.
>
> After following instructions for using this library, you can simply
>   call:
>
> ```
> var imageData=$base64.encode(image);
> ```
>
> Don't forget to inject in your module:
>
> ```
> .module('myApp', ['base64'])
> ```

Comment: This plugin encodes my image url, no the actual image

Answer (score 2):

You can use the angular custom directive to convert the image base64. 
directive.js

```
myApp.directive('imgUpload', ['$rootScope',function (rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      var extensions = 'jpeg ,jpg, png, gif';
      elem.on('change', function () {
      reader.readAsDataURL(elem[0].files[0]);
      var filename = elem[0].files[0].name;

        var extensionlist = filename.split('.');
        var extension =extensionlist[extensionlist.length - 1];
            if(extensions.indexOf(extension) == -1){
                alert("File extension , Only 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp' are allowed.");       

            }else{
                    scope.file = elem[0].files[0];
                    scope.imageName = filename;
                }
      });

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {

              scope.image = e.target.result;
              scope.$apply();

            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

Html:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input id="image" class="hidden" type="file" img-upload ng-model="imageName" name="imageName">
  <img ng-src="{{image}}" height="100" width="100" ng-show="image"/>
  <label for="image" class="btn btn-success btn-xs pull-center" name="upload" Value="">Upload Photo</label>
</div>
```

Now you need to add your code in controller which works for storing image or file in database.

Answer (score 1):

If your image data is already in base64, try

```
<img alt="{{p.alt}}" data-ng-src="{{'data:image/png;base64,'+p.Photo}}" class="photo" />
```

Comment: Though, in theory, this is not wrong, it is the opposite of what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Code to upload the image in 64 bit in Angularjs

Html code

```
<div class="col-md-8">
  <img ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{model.Logo}}" id="photo-id" />
  <input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this)" id="photo-upload" />
</div>
```

Angular code:

```
 $scope.uploadFile = function (input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                reader.onload = function (e) {

                    $('#photo-id').attr('src', e.target.result);                    
                    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                    var imageElement = document.createElement("img");

                    imageElement.setAttribute = $('<img>', { src: e.target.result });
                    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                    imageElement.setAttribute.load(function()
                    {
                        debugger;
                        canvas.width = this.width;
                        canvas.height = this.height;


                        context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
                        var base64Image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

                        var data = base64Image.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");

                        $scope.model.Logo = data;
                    });



                }


            }
        }
```

for more go to link:
http://vikasbishtangular.blogspot.in/2017/04/code-to-upload-image-in-64-bit-in.html

Comment: Hint: that preview window exists for a reason. Dont drop code here which isn't actually readable (like those html parts you have)!