# Get Image name and base64 format image path in cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic2

I need to get image name as well as base64 image when user select an image from photo library.I am using cordova Camera plugin to get image from gallery,but i am not getting image name and base64 image at the same time.

```
// to get base64 image
    Camera.getPicture({
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        targetWidth: 1000,
        targetHeight: 1000
    }).then((imageData) => {
      // imageData is a base64 encoded string
        this.base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;

        alert("this.base64Image="+this.base64Image);
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
//to get image URL
    Camera.getPicture({
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        targetWidth: 1000,
        targetHeight: 1000
    }).then((imagePath) => {
      // imageData is a base64 encoded string
        this.imagePath = imagePath;

        alert("this.imagePath="+this.imagePath);
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

How can i combine both of these call in single click?

Comment: shall I show you cordova code?because I am not familiar with ionic

Answer (score 1):

> [Documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/#module_Camera.DestinationType) says Camera.DestinationType : enum, can be used one at a time as FILE_URI or DATA_URL or NATIVE_URI

But if you want both base64 and file path, you can [convert image to base64 in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905381/convert-image-to-base64-in-angularjs)