# Angular/Javascript:File or Blob inside Json data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

can i send file inside a json through ajax:

```
colors: [
{_id: "5bec42f02797800f447241d1", color: "#777", image: File(79666)},
{_id: "5bec8cf91fb21b3a2477d817", color: "#566", image: File(79666)}
]
```

If not how to send this data through ajax.

code:

```
formData.append('colors', JSON.stringify(data));
```

i am getting data.colors[0].image as {} while sending

Comment: thx but my ques is different.

Comment: You should convert file to `base64`. Then you can

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert image to base64 in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905381/convert-image-to-base64-in-angularjs)

Comment: ok any other way other than base64 cause i think image to base64 is not good(for large files)

Answer (score 0):

you can convert your file to Base64 string and send it through JSON.

On receiving, convert this Base64 string back to desired file format

This may help on how to convert file to base64:
[How to convert file to base64 in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280818/how-to-convert-file-to-base64-in-javascript)

Comment: ok any other way other than base64 cause i think image to base64 is not good(for large files)& thx

Comment: JSON supports string, number, boolean, array, object, null. So no, there's no other way if you want to send it in a JSON