# how to reset the value of file controls in html

Tags: jquery, html

i used file control in a html page i want to remove the file location from control when user click on reset button.

```
$("#control").val("");
```

if i run this code he not work in Chrome but in Firefox

what i do to unselect the file who is not selected in file upload control.

how i can reset the controls without reset the whole form. are any thing exist to do this.

Comment: Have a look at the top answer to a similar question, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-typefile-using-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this article](http://gusiev.com/2009/04/clear-upload-file-input-field/), you can use the following JavaScript method to clear the HTML input file control's value:

```
function clearFileInputField(tagId) {
    document.getElementById(tagId).innerHTML = 
                    document.getElementById(tagId).innerHTML;
}
```

Or, if refactored in jQuery, this should work as well:

```
$("#control").html($("#control").html());
```

Answer (score 5):

The other solution didn't work me. I used the following code and it worked for me.

```
$("#control").val(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this JS code without any external library:

```
var file = document.getElementById("file1");
    file.value = file.defaultValue;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you using jQuery then following also can be utilize.

```
$('"#control"').prop('value', '');
```