# jQuery: how to clear context of a FileUpload control of asp.net

Tags: jquery

I know to clear context of a textbox, using $('#textbox1').val("");
But how to clear context of a FileUpload control. I mean to erase the content of it's textbox. For example, I first choose a file using FileUpload control, which it shows c:\user\1.png. Now I want to clear it by using jQuery.

```
$('#FileUpload1').val("");
```

apprently does not work here.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#FileUpload1').val("");
```

won't work on ie.

document.getElementById("#FileUpload1").createTextRange().execCommand('delete');` will work on ie

or you can use
var file = document.getElementById("<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>");
 $(file).parent().html($(file).parent().html());

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#FileUpload1').val("");
```

you're missing '

Comment: I'm sure, I am not missing close quote in my code. Sorry for typo in the post question.

Answer (score 0):

Your FileUpload control will be rendered as a div with an input of type "file" and a client ID determined by your ClientIDMode. In many circumstances, it will be the same as your control's server-side ID.

There's an excellent explanation of how ASP.net generates client-side IDs from server-side ones [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx)

(Or, you could just be missing a closing quote.)

Comment: Actually I use $("[id$='FileUpload1']").val(""), which does not work

Answer (score 0):

might try this

```
<input type="file" id="control"/>
<button id="clear">Clear</button>
var control = $("#control");

$("#clear").on("click", function () {
    control.replaceWith( control = control.clone( true ) );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/dAQVM/

taken from here : [Clearing <input type='file' /> using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery)