# Why doesn't IE reset file input field?

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload

I've modified my current form to trigger a form submission after a user chooses a file for upload.  After the upload is complete I call:

```
$('#file').val('');
```

to reset the file input field.

```
HTML
<input name="file" type="file" id="file"/>
```

This works on Chrome, FF, and Safari but doesn't work in IE.  Is there a workaround or a better solution for IE?

Comment: Here's a duplicate for this: [Clearing <input type='file' /> using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery)

Comment: @jabclab so wat ?? that ques. dsnt have any accepted answer... and this quest gave me the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't change the value of a file input type, as that would introduce a security vulnerability. Instead, just replace the file input with a new one. Instead of `$('#file').val('')`, do this:

```
$('#file').replaceWith('<input name="file" type="file" id="file"/>');
```

Even better would be to clone a copy of the original version and store it in memory. When you need to replace it, just used the cloned copy, and again clone it. So, something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var empty_input = $('#file').clone();

    $('#the-form').on('change', '#file', function(el) {
        $('#the-form').submit(); // assuming the target is a hidden iframe
        $(this).replaceWith(empty_input.clone());
    });
})
```

Note that I'm using the delegated version with [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) so the event will still work on the new input right after it's replaced.

Comment: That worked great...I never considered the security risk, thanks!