# How to only clear file upload field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/buyC9/128/

I want to clear only the file upload field when pressed on clear.

My HTML:

```
<h1>Upload image:</h1>
<input type="file" name="blog[opload]" id="blog_opload" class="imagec">
<input type="url" size="50" name="blog[url]" id="blog_url" class="imagec">
<div id="preview">
</div>
```

My Jquery:

```
$('input').change(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    if (this.value === "") {
        $('.imagec').prop('disabled', false);
        this.disabled = false;
        $('#preview').hide();
    } else {
        $('.imagec').prop('disabled', true);
        el.prop('disabled', false);
        alert(el.val());
        if (el.attr('type') == 'url') {
            $('#preview').show().html('<img src=' + '"' + el.val() + '"' + ' />');
        }
    }
});

function reset_html(id) {
    $('.' + id).html( $('.' + id).html() );
}

var imagec_index = 0;
    $('input[type=file]').each(function() {
    imagec_index++;
    $(this).wrap('<div id="imagec_' + imagec_index + '"></div>');
    $(this).after('<input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="reset_html(\'imagec_' + imagec_index + '\')" />');
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use plugin for that?

Comment: What do you mean "pressed on clear"?

Comment: When the button "clear" is click the file upload field should be cleared :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Quick answer is replace it:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery)

```
$("#clear").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#control").replaceWith("<input type='file' id='control' />");
});

<input type="file" id="control" />
<a href="#" id="clear">Clear</a>
```

Answer (score 8):

How about:

```
$('input[value="Clear"]').click(function(){
    $('#blog_opload').val('');
});
```

Example: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eGFev/)**

You could also get rid of `onclick="reset_html(\'imagec_' + imagec_index + '\')"` if you use this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do simply

```
  $("#filuploadId")[0].value = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you meant to use the ID selector but instead are using class selector.

```
$('.' + id).html( $('.' + id).html() );
```

should be

```
$('#' + id).html( $('#' + id).html() );
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buyC9/130/)