# How to make a file upload field empty in struts2 using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, struts2

I have a file upload field,that is,`<s:file> </s:file>`. And I have a button "clear". On clicking this button, the field which has some file link should become empty.Could anyone help me with this?

**My code:**

```
<s:file id="filetestplanid2" name="testPlanDto.testFile" label="test"
        tooltipIconPath="../../KY/images/common/buttons/uploadBtn.png"  
        title="Browse" tooltip="Browse..."  cssClass="file" />
```

**My javascript:**

```
$('#filetestplanid2').val(null);
$('#filetestplanid2').val("");
```

I tried these but no luck.

**Also tried:**

```
var file = $("#filetestplanid2"); file.replaceWith(file = file.clone(true));

$('#filetestplanid2').html( $('#filetestplanid2').html() );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of 'How to only clear file upload field?' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118738/how-to-only-clear-file-upload-field

Comment: Your example shows different IDs.  Are you sure you're trying to empty the correct element?

Comment: Sorry, by mistake, I have included another id.

Comment: @Vignesh: No, this is not a duplicate. The one which you mentioned is about normal file upload. But this is with struts.

Comment: @kishore That makes zero difference; S2 tags render HTML--what else could they do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clearing <input type='file' /> using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

```
<input type="button" onclick="clearFileElement('filetestplanid2');" />
```

Vanilla JS

```
function clearFileElement(fileId){
    document.getElementById(fileId).value = '';
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2nxGr/

Can't make it works with jQuery but basically you have to substitute it with a clone of itself (with all the properties, gained using `clone(true)`).

Just stick to the plain JS version, it works like a charm.

**EDIT**

I've found now a very smart solution that works on every browser: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13351234/1654265

Comment: @kishore Then check your assumptions: inspect the element and see its ID. Check the JS console. Debug.

Comment: The first solution works too, and IT IS an answer. I edited to add a better one I found, to help more users. Could you please stop downvoting my answers ? I mean like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17060676/1654265

Answer (score 0):

You can make it empty using Jquery too, just like this:

`$("#filetestplanid2")[0].value = ""`

or

```
$("#filetestplanid2").get(0).value = ""
```