# How to Reset Struts2 File control

Tags: javascript, struts2

I have a Struts File control in my page. I would like to reset my file control if there is an invalid entry. Following are the things i noticed:
1) Most browsers don't let us to reset the file control.
2) What we can do is replace the existing control with a new control and copy all the original control's properties.
I did this by doing :

```
var newInput = document.createElement("input");
    newInput.type = "file";
    newInput.id = document.getElementById("myfilecontrol").id;
    newInput.name = document.getElementById("myfilecontrol").name;
    newInput.className = document.getElementById("myfilecontrol").className;
    newInput.style.cssText = document.getElementById("myfilecontrol").style.cssText;
    document.getElementById("myfilecontrol").parentNode.replaceChild(newInput, document.getElementById("myfilecontrol"));
```

My problem is that this works only once. It is the old control that calls the validation method and not the new one. Is there any way i can make my new control call the validation method automatically ? or is there another better way to reset a struts file control ? (Refreshing the page is not an option.) Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by *reset* file control?

Comment: If a user has selected a wrong type of file. I want to show an error message and then clear the selection made. That is, I want to clear the File control and make it empty.

Comment: It should be clear by default, isn't it?

Comment: once the user selects a wrong file, we have to clear the field after displaying the error message. It wont be cleared automatically.

Comment: You mean javascript validation? Why don't you say so in your post?

Comment: What is `x` in your code?

Comment: x is the identification of the first control. I passed it using "this".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17168519/1654265

Comment: @AndreaLigios: we cant set the value of a file control in struts as empty like the way mentioned in the link you provided. This is a security feature in most browsers.

Comment: Open the link in the answer.