# Clear upload file name from file uploader

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="flIcon" />
```

In Jquery:

```
$('#btnAddNew').click(function(event) {
                    alert($("#flIcon").attr('file'));
                    $("div#flIcon").replaceWith("<input type='file' id='flIcon'/>");

                });
```

I see in FireBug when page Load:

```
<div id="uniform-flIcon" class="uploader">
<input id="flIcon" class=" " type="file" style="opacity: 0;">
<span class="filename" style="-moz-user-select: none;">document-save.png</span>
<span class="action" style="-moz-user-select: none;">Choose File</span>
</div>
```

I try it from this ref.[Clearing <input type='file' /> using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery)But its not work for me.Is there any browser compatibility issue or i am missing some thing.Thanks.

Comment: its working fine with $("#flIcon").replaceWith('..'); here---http://jsfiddle.net/XFyuw/3/

Comment: $('#btnAddNew').on('click(function(event){ alert($("#flIcon").attr('file')); $("div#flIcon").replaceWith("<input type='file' id='flIcon' />"); });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<input type="file" id="flIcon" />
<div id="btnAddNew">Clear</div>
```

and then:

```
$('#btnAddNew').click(function(event) {
    $("#flIcon").replaceWith("<input type='file' id='flIcon'/>").html();
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes Darin's solution works well.

Alternatively you could also clear by doing this using JQuery..

```
$('#flIcon').val('');
```