# how to reset <input type = "file"> in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am developing a metro app with VS2012 and Javascript

I want to reset the contents of my file input:

```html
<input type="file" id="uploadCaptureInputFile" class="win-content colors" accept="image/*" />
```

How should I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by content?

Comment: do you mean, after the user selects a file, you want to reset the selected file to "nothing"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery

Comment: Yes, the path on my input type= file how to clear that what's the magic word :p

Comment: @Dhaval Marthak: yes it works but I was looking a solution either with pure Javascript or WinJS so far I implemented your solution with jQuery and it Worked

Comment: it [seems](http://jsfiddle.net/kojk65rv/) that a simple `inputElement.value = ""` does the trick just fine without resorting to cloning or wrapping as suggested. Works in CH(46), IE(11) and FF(41)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I clear an HTML file input with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703228/how-can-i-clear-an-html-file-input-with-javascript)

Comment: I found a answer that workds for me in another topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear File Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617738/how-to-clear-file-input)

Answer (score 530):

The jQuery solution that @dhaval-marthak posted in the comments obviously works, but if you look at the actual jQuery call it's pretty easy to see what jQuery is doing, just setting the `value` attribute to an empty string. So in "pure" JavaScript it would be:

```
document.getElementById("uploadCaptureInputFile").value = "";
```

Comment: Thanks! If you already have the jquery reference anyway, $input.val("") will work as usual.

Comment: @2ndGAB Hmm... I only have 45.0.1 so I can't test... anyone else?

Comment: @2ndGAB Correction, My Firefox just updated to 46.0.1 and this code still works there. Can you confirm?

Comment: @jakerella that's strange, for me, set an input file selector value trigs a Security exception. The only solution I successfully use is `$(#myfileselector).trigger('fileselect', [1, ""]);`

Comment: Weirdly, this works, but setting the value to `undefined` or deleting it does not. `null` works, but I don't know if that's better than `''`.

Comment: input.type = '';
input.type = 'file'; //enjoy

Comment: @Maxmaxmaximus This will not work across browsers. I just tried in Safari and setting the `type` to blank string changed the "file" field to a blank text field, but then setting the `type` back to "file" did not work (it stayed a text field). This is a [security restriction some browsers still have](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/change-type-of-input-field-with-jquery). However, setting the `value` to an empty string did still work.

Comment: This answer is not good enough. If the input is set as `required`, resetting the field should make the field invalid again. Unfortunately in this case, it is still valid, so the form will submit, although with no value.

Comment: jQuery was not requested and should not be given as answer unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 97):

You need to wrap `<input type = “file”>` in to `<form>` tags and then you can reset input by resetting your form:

```
onClick="this.form.reset()"
```

Comment: This is the correct method. It works in all browsers and does not conflict with any protections that browsers implement to prevent rogue scripts from messing around with file input's .value.

Comment: Kinda cool, not for me though, cause it also resets other fields on this form.

Comment: A similar jQuery solution could be `$("form").get(0).reset();`. The `.get(0)` will return the actual form element so you can use the `reset()` function.

Answer (score 88):

This is the BEST solution:

```
input.value = ''

if(!/safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
  input.type = ''
  input.type = 'file'
}
```

Of all the answers here this is the fastest solution. No input clone, no form reset!

I checked it in all browsers (it even has IE8 support).

Comment: Is there any specific reason to reset the `input.type` too? Setting just the value to `''` is giving the expected result.

Comment: This needs some more upvotes or something, I took far too long to find this answer, this is the only one I found that works on IE.

Comment: input.value = '' throws an exception to the console in IE11. However resetting input.type works on all browsers without any error.

Comment: This answer is not good enough. If the input is set as `required`, resetting the field should make the field invalid again. Unfortunately in this case, it is still valid, so the form will submit, although with no value.

Comment: I would set value to `null`, but basically same thing.

Comment: Why the test on safari? And if the test is true, no reset?

Answer (score 66):

In case you have the following:

```
<input type="file" id="fileControl">
```

then just do:

```
$("#fileControl").val('');
```

to reset the file control.

Comment: Best solution IMHO.

Comment: Or use DOM: `inputFileEl.value = '';`

Comment: is using "val" in javascript source code cause some security issues?

Comment: @novonimo No, since all it does is set the value of an input. And if someone wanted to, they could just use their browser's DevTools to run JavaScript.

Answer (score 56):

**Another solution (without selecting HTML DOM elements )**

If you added 'change' event listener on that input, then in javascript code you can call (for some specified conditions):

```
event.target.value = '';
```

For example in HTML:

```
<input type="file" onChange="onChangeFunction(event)">
```

And in javascript:

```
onChangeFunction(event) {
  let fileList = event.target.files;
  let file = fileList[0];
  let extension = file.name.match(/(?<=\.)\w+$/g)[0].toLowerCase(); // assuming that this file has any extension

  if (extension === 'jpg') {
    alert('Good file extension!');
  }
  else {
    event.target.value = '';
    alert('Wrong file extension! File input is cleared.');
  }
```

Comment: Another way to angular2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165271/how-to-reset-selected-file-with-input-tag-file-type-in-angular-2

Comment: This will only work on filenames which contain just a single `.` in front of file extension.

Comment: That's right, I have edited the code and provided more universal approach to get a file extension.

Comment: This is the only solution that allows the `change` event to re-fire if the user subsequently selects the same file.

Answer (score 45):

You can just clone it and replace it with itself, with all events still attached:

```
<input type="file" id="control">
```

and

```
var input = $("#control");

function something_happens() {
    input.replaceWith(input.val('').clone(true));
};
```

Thanks : Css-tricks.com

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't reset input value, see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/698svryg/). For a better solution, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13351234/3549014).

Comment: @Gyrocode.com This jsFiddle doesn't work if the image is uploaded second time after reset.

Comment: @SarthakSinghal, that's exactly what I meant. The answer above (demonstrated by this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/698svryg/)) doesn't work because once file is upload the second time the reset stops working. I'm surprised this incorrect answer got so many votes. For a better solution, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13351234/3549014) or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31751943/3549014).

Comment: @SarthakSinghal, Unfortunately you wrote the wrong code, you should have done http://jsfiddle.net/cL1LooLe

Comment: @RogerRussel: Exactly... I was wondering myself how come upper answers were saying that it only works once which is a clear indicator that some sort of reference is being lost. And that was actually the case because the initially created the input reference that was later replaced with a new input element.

Comment: Just resetting the `value` like in other answers seems much more straightforward than manipulating the DOM.

Answer (score 42):

```
document.getElementById('uploadFile').value = "";
```

Will work, But if you use **Angular**
It will say  "Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.any"

document.getElementById() returns the type HTMLElement which does not contain a value property. So, cast it into HTMLInputElement

```
(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('uploadFile')).value = "";
```

EXTRA :-

However, we should not use DOM manipulation (document.xyz()) in angular.

To do that angular has provided @ViewChild, @ViewChildren, etc which are document.querySelector(), document.queryselectorAll() respectively.

Even I haven't read it. Better to follows expert's blogs

Go through this [link1](https://blog.angularindepth.com/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02), [link2](https://blog.angularindepth.com/working-with-dom-in-angular-unexpected-consequences-and-optimization-techniques-682ac09f6866)

Comment: glad I don't have to use angular!

Comment: No. FIx would be there. Only I found this one. Which you are using then?

Comment: Sorry, I was being sarcastic...I just use document.getElementById('uploadFile').value = ""; as I don't use angular.

Comment: Nice one. I thought the same, But, use Angular/ React/ VUe. These are powerful frameworks for routing, component, service, dom manipulation override implemenration

Comment: This doesnt work in Anguar 13!! Nothing works. Setting the value to '' doesnt work. Setting the file list of new DataTransfer().files doesnt work. Nothing works!

Answer (score 34):

#### SOLUTION

The following code worked for me with jQuery. It works in every browser and allows to preserve events and custom properties.

```
var $el = $('#uploadCaptureInputFile');
$el.wrap('<form>').closest('form').get(0).reset();
$el.unwrap();
```

#### DEMO

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/yfeo529g/) for code and demonstration.

#### LINKS

See [How to reset file input with JavaScript](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/how-to-reset-file-input-with-javascript/) for more information.

Comment: @alessadro, no, just element `<input type="file">` with specific ID.

Comment: Thanks clarify your answer :) +1

Comment: This is the cleanest and most browser-compliant solution I have found yet - thank you.

Answer (score 28):

Resetting a file upload button is so easy using **pure JavaScript**!

There are few ways to do it, but the must straightforward way which is working well in many browser is changing the filed value to nothing, that way the upload filed gets reset, also try to use pure javascript rather than any framework, I created the code below, just check it out (ES6):

```js
function resetFile() {
  const file = document.querySelector('.file');
  file.value = '';
}
```

```html
<input type="file" class="file" />
<button onclick="resetFile()">Reset file</button>
```

Comment: how to do with jquery

Comment: @AnandChoudhary this works inside jQuery as well, but you can replace const file = document.querySelector('.file'); with const file = $('.file'); or just do $('.file').val(""); to empty it

Answer (score 17):

I use for vuejs

```
   <input
          type="file"
          ref="fileref"
          @change="onChange"/>

this.$refs.fileref.value = ''
```

Comment: Thanks man! I thought I will never find a solution with vuejs :D, you mad my day!

Comment: Worked like  a charm! Thank you

Answer (score 17):

I miss an other Solution here (2021):
I use `FileList` to interact with file input.

Since there is no way to create a `FileList` object, I use `DataTransfer`, that brings clean FilleList with it.

I reset it with:

```
  file_input.files=new DataTransfer().files
```

In my case this perfectly fits, since I interact only via `FileList` with my encapsulated file input element.

Answer (score 11):

The reseting input file is on very single

`$('input[type=file]').val(null);`

If you bind reset the file in change other field of the form, or load form with ajax.

**This example is applicable**

**selector** for example is `$('input[type=text]')` or any element of the form

**event** `click`, `change`, or any event

```
$('body').delegate('event', 'selector', function(){
     $('input[type=file]').val(null) ;
});
```

Comment: Or you can use `$('input[type=file]').val('') ;` also

Answer (score 10):

**My Best Solution**

```
$(".file_uplaod_input").val('');  // this is working best ):
```

Comment: How is this different from the first answer and the comments on that answer?

Answer (score 9):

There are many approaches and i will suggest to go with ref attachment to input.

```
<input
    id="image"
    type="file"
    required
    ref={ref => this.fileInput = ref}
    multiple
    onChange={this.onFileChangeHandler}
/>
```

to clear value after submit.

```
this.fileInput.value = "";
```

Answer (score 6):

With **IE 10** I resolved the problem with :

```
    var file = document.getElementById("file-input");
    file.removeAttribute('value');
    file.parentNode.replaceChild(file.cloneNode(true),file);
```

where :

```
<input accept="image/*" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this)" id="file-input" type="file"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use:

```
$('input[type=file]').val('');
```

Answer (score 6):

```js
document.getElementById("uploadCaptureInputFile").value = "";
```

Answer (score 5):

With angular you can create a template variable and set the value to `null`

```
<input type="file" #fileUploader />
<button (click)="fileUploader.value = null">Reset from UI</button>
```

Or you can create a method to reset like this

*component.ts*

```
  @ViewChild('fileUploader') fileUploader:ElementRef;

  resetFileUploader() { 
    this.fileUploader.nativeElement.value = null;
  }
```

*template*

```
<input type="file"/>
<button (click)="resetFileUploader()">Reset from Component</button>
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-file-reset)

Answer (score 5):

```
<input type="file" id="mfile" name="mfile">
<p>Reset</p>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("p").click(function(){

            $("#mfile").val('');
            return false;

    });
});
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25734470)

Comment: $("#mfile").val('') will empty the file input field.

Answer (score 3):

You can´t reset that since it is an  read-only file. you can clone it to workaround the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You should try this:

```
$("#uploadCaptureInputFile").val('');
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced the issue with ng2-file-upload for angular. if you are looking for the solution in angular refer below code

**HTML:**

`<input type="file" name="myfile"` **#activeFrameinputFile** `ng2FileSelect [uploader]="frameUploader" (change)="frameUploader.uploadAll()" />`

**component**

`import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';`

`@ViewChild('`**activeFrameinputFile**`')`**InputFrameVariable**`: ElementRef;`

`this.frameUploader.onSuccessItem = (item, response, status, headers) => {`

```
`this.`**InputFrameVariable**`.nativeElement.value = '';`
```

`};`

Answer (score 3):

This could be done like this

```js
var inputfile= $('#uploadCaptureInputFile')
$('#reset').on('click',function(){
inputfile.replaceWith(inputfile.val('').clone(true));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" id="uploadCaptureInputFile" class="win-content colors" accept="image/*" />
<a href="" id="reset">Reset</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery solution:

```
    $('input').on('change',function(){
                $(this).get(0).value = '';
                $(this).get(0).type = '';
                $(this).get(0).type = 'file';
            });
```

Comment: Consider padding this answer out to explain how it works.

Comment: @Bugs guess this speaks for itself. When the file input's `on change` event is triggered the value gets cleared. The type of the input gets resetted from none to file.

Comment: @Jordy yes I know what it does :) I was just thinking that with a dozen other answers it would be worth trying to make it stand out. It appeared whilst I was reviewing. They could in fact copy your comment to pad it out that bit more. It's always worth trying to explain why you feel the code fixes the OPs problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have several files in your form but only want one of them to be reset:

if you use boostrap, jquery, filestyle to display the input file form :

```
$("#"+idInput).filestyle('clear');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var fileInput = $('#uploadCaptureInputFile');
fileInput.replaceWith(fileInput.val('').clone(true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for dynamic controls too.

Javascript

```
<input type="file" onchange="FileValidate(this)" />

function FileValidate(object) {
    if ((object.files[0].size / 1024 / 1024) > 1) {   //greater than 1 MB         
        $(object).val('');
    }     
}
```

JQuery

```
<input type="file" class="UpoloadFileSize">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.UpoloadFileSize').bind('change', function () {                
        if ((this.files[0].size / 1024000) > 1.5) { //greater than 1.5 MB
            $(this).val('');
            alert('Size exceeded !!');
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function resetImageField() {
    var $el = $('#uploadCaptureInputFile');                                        
    $el.wrap('<form>').closest('form').get(0).reset();
    $el.unwrap();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="uploadCaptureInputFile" class="win-content colors" accept="image/*" />
<button onclick="resetImageField()">Reset field</button>
```