# scope.$watch not working when updating model

Tags: angularjs, directive

I have the following problem. The $watch event gets called when I manually select a file. But when I do it by using the following

```
$scope.clear = function() {
    $scope.logo = null;
  };
```

it doesn't fire the event. Any ideas?

Here's the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zQGpubml5ew4WhQnGzCA?p=preview)

Comment: neither does ng-change, because the changes made in javascript are not watched by angular.

Comment: Here's a plunkr that is similar to what I want:http://plnkr.co/edit/xLM9VX?p=preview  How can I modify it to have scope variable like document

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with input type file. the input type[file] does not get reset as other inputs do.

please read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549241/how-to-reset-input-type-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery).

the suggested solution is:

```
<input type="file" id="control"/>
```

and corrosponding js

```
var control = $("#control");

$("#clear").on("click", function () {
    control.replaceWith( control = control.clone( true ) );
});
```

you can always write a directive which would make it much more reusable.

Comment: why this plunkr works plnkr.co/edit/xLM9VX?p=preview ? The event gets called when you click on the clear button.