# Add a page refresh button by using R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm making an app and I need to add a button to refresh page (same function to press F5). Is there anyone can share a piece of code to implement it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what would it do differently than the refresh button in the browser?

Comment: Please do expand on what you mean by "refresh" - do you want to literally do a page refresh or do you just want all the inputs to go back to their initial state?

Comment: Actually I want all the inputs to go back to the initial values. I have a upload input and I don't know how to reset this input value as null. So I thought refresh page might be a shortcut. @daattali, do you have any idea on how to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I do have a very simple and nice solution <strike>but it won't work for a file input</strike>.

Here's a solution that'll work for all inputs <strike>except a file input</strike>:

**UPDATE 2017: this solution did not work on file inputs for the first 2 years, but it does now.**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    div(
      id = "form",
      textInput("text", "Text", ""),
      selectInput("select", "Select", 1:5),
      actionButton("refresh", "Refresh")
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$refresh, {
      shinyjs::reset("form")
    })
  }
))
```

When you press "Refresh", all inputs will be reset to their initial values. **This is what the poster said in a comment that they actually want to do.**

<strike>But file inputs are very strange and it's hard to "reset" them. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549241/how-to-reset-input-type-file). You could hack some JavaScript together to try to almost kind of reset an input field if you want.</strike>

However, for completeness, you can also refresh the entire page. The easiest way to do that is with `session$reload()`. You can also do it with {shinyjs}:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    shinyjs::extendShinyjs(text = "shinyjs.refresh_page = function() { location.reload(); }", functions = "refresh_page"),
    textInput("text", "Text", ""),
    actionButton("refresh", "Refresh")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$refresh, {
      shinyjs::js$refresh_page()
    })
  }
))
```

Disclaimer: both these solutions use a package I wrote, [`shinyjs`](https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs)

Comment: Thanks, daattali. I will try to use it on my app. BTW, let's go back to the button question I asked. Do you know any way to add a url to an attribution, for example, if I click a button then it will open that url in browser?

Comment: Can't you just use a simple <a> tag? `tags$a(href = "http://www.google.com", "Click me")`

Comment: @daattali. Thanks for this. You say above that this should work with anything but file inputs. Could you please confirm that it should work with radioButtons()? Thanks

Comment: It will work for radio buttons, you can try it easily

Comment: Error: shinyjs: extendShinyjs: `functions` argument must be provided. See the documentation for `?extendShinyjs` for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I have a drop-down list input:

```
selectInput("domain", label = h4("Domain:"), choices = Domain, selected = CurrentDomain)
```

The choices set  is based on  a table in the database. It should change after I add or delete record from the table.

When I was experimenting with your reset or refresh function, the choice set could not reflect the changes and always stay the same. However, when I use the "reload" button provided by the browser, the choice set will update immediately. I am wondering whether you have a reset/refresh solution that is equivalent to the "reload" button of the browser.

I provided my code here, which will not work but will give you an idea what I want to do.

```
conn<-odbcDriverConnect(connString)
 SystemInfo<-sqlQuery(conn, 'SELECT * FROM [DQ].[DQSystemInfo]',       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
 close(conn)

 Domain<-unique(SystemInfo$Domain)
 Domain<-c(Domain,'NEW')
 SubDomain<-unique(SystemInfo$SubDomain[SystemInfo$Domain==Domain[1]])
 SubDomain<-c(SubDomain,'NEW')
 CurrentDomain<-Domain[1]
 CurrentSubDomain<-SubDomain[1]
 SystemInfo1<-SystemInfo[SystemInfo$Domain==CurrentDomain &      SystemInfo$SubDomain==CurrentSubDomain,]

  jsResetCode <- "shinyjs.reset = function() {history.go(0)}"

 shinyApp(


ui = fluidPage(
shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
shinyjs::extendShinyjs(text = "shinyjs.refresh = function() { location.reload(); }"),
#  div(
#      id = "form",
fluidRow(
  column(6, selectInput("domain", label = h4("Domain:"), 
                        choices = Domain, selected = CurrentDomain)),
  column(6,uiOutput("Condition2"))
),

#  fluidRow(column(2, verbatimTextOutput("value"))),

fluidRow(
  column(6, uiOutput("Condition1")),
  column(6,uiOutput("Condition3"))
),

    extendShinyjs(text = jsResetCode),

fluidRow(
  column(2, actionButton("submit", "Save", class="btn btn-primary btn-lg")),
  column(2, actionButton("cancel", "Cancel", class="btn btn-primary btn-

lg")),
      column(2, actionButton("delete", "Delete", class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"))
    )
    #)
  ),




  server = function(input, output) {

    observeEvent(input$domain, {
      if (input$domain=='NEW') {
        shinyjs::disable("domain")
    shinyjs::disable("delete") 
    CurrentSubDomain<-'NEW'

    output$Condition1 = renderUI({
      textInput("domainT",label = "", value = "")
    })

    output$Condition3 = renderUI({
      textInput("subdomainT", label = "",value = "")
    })

})   

  } else {
    CurrentDomain<-input$domain
    SubDomain<-unique(SystemInfo$SubDomain[SystemInfo$Domain==input$domain])
    SubDomain<-c(SubDomain,'NEW')}

  output$Condition2 = renderUI({
    selectInput("subdomain", label = h4("SubDomain:"),
                choices = SubDomain, selected =CurrentSubDomain)
  })

})


observeEvent(input$subdomain, {

  if (input$subdomain=='NEW') {
    shinyjs::disable("domain")  
    shinyjs::disable("subdomain")
    shinyjs::disable("delete") 

    output$Condition3 = renderUI({
      textInput("subdomainT", label = "", value = "")
    })


  } else {
    CurrentSubDomain<-input$subdomain
    conn<-odbcDriverConnect(connString)
    SystemInfo<-sqlQuery(conn, 'SELECT * FROM [DQ].[DQSystemInfo]', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    close(conn)
    SystemInfo1<-SystemInfo[SystemInfo$Domain==input$domain & SystemInfo$SubDomain==input$subdomain,]


  }
})


observeEvent(input$submit, {



    conn<-odbcDriverConnect(connString)
    DQ.DQSystemInfo<-SystemInfo[FALSE,c("Domain","SubDomain")]
    DQ.DQSystemInfo[1,]<-c("","","","","","","",0,48)
    DQ.DQSystemInfo$Domain<-ifelse(input$domain=='NEW',input$domainT,input$domain)
    DQ.DQSystemInfo$SubDomain<-input$subdomainT
    varType1 <- c("varchar(20)", "varchar(20)" )
    names(varType1)<-colnames(DQ.DQSystemInfo)
    sqlSave(conn, DQ.DQSystemInfo, append = TRUE, rownames = FALSE, varTypes = varType1)
    close(conn)

  # js$reset()
  #shinyjs::reset("form")
  # js$reset("form")

  conn<-odbcDriverConnect(connString)
  SystemInfo<-sqlQuery(conn, 'SELECT * FROM [DQ].[DQSystemInfo]', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  close(conn)

  Domain<-unique(SystemInfo$Domain)
  Domain<-c(Domain,'NEW')
  SubDomain<-unique(SystemInfo$SubDomain[SystemInfo$Domain==Domain[1]])
  SubDomain<-c(SubDomain,'NEW')
  CurrentDomain<-Domain[1]
  CurrentSubDomain<-SubDomain[1]
  SystemInfo1<-SystemInfo[SystemInfo$Domain==CurrentDomain & SystemInfo$SubDomain==CurrentSubDomain,]
  shinyjs::js$refresh()

})

observeEvent(input$cancel, {
  #js$reset()
  #shinyjs::reset("form")
  #js$reset("form")
  shinyjs::js$refresh()
})

observeEvent(input$delete, {
  conn<-odbcDriverConnect(connString)
  delete.query <- paste0("DELETE DQ.DQSystemInfo WHERE Domain='",
                         input$domain,"' and SubDomain='",input$subdomain,"'")
  sqlQuery(conn, delete.query)
  close(conn)

  #js$reset()
  # shinyjs::reset("form")
  # js$reset("form")

  conn<-odbcDriverConnect(connString)
  SystemInfo<-sqlQuery(conn, 'SELECT * FROM [DQ].[DQSystemInfo]', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  close(conn)

  Domain<-unique(SystemInfo$Domain)
  Domain<-c(Domain,'NEW')
  SubDomain<-unique(SystemInfo$SubDomain[SystemInfo$Domain==Domain[1]])
  SubDomain<-c(SubDomain,'NEW')
  CurrentDomain<-Domain[1]
  CurrentSubDomain<-SubDomain[1]
  SystemInfo1<-SystemInfo[SystemInfo$Domain==CurrentDomain & SystemInfo$SubDomain==CurrentSubDomain,]
  shinyjs::js$refresh()      
    })

  },options = list(height = 520))
```