# Refreshing a R shiny session from within the server part

Tags: javascript, r, session, shiny, shinyjs

My R shiny App loads information, and I want that before these info be loaded, the session be automatically refreshed.

A similar question has been asked several times, but the answer always comes with a button. For example:
[Page refresh Button in R shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34142841/page-refresh-button-in-r-shiny)

I tried to include the reset code in an observe function in the server part, without success:

```
observe({
jsResetCode <- "shinyjs.reset = function() {history.go(0)}" # Define the js     method that resets the page
useShinyjs()                                      
extendShinyjs(text = jsResetCode)       
})
```

How can I automatically refresh a R shiny session from within a function?

Comment: The `session` object has a `reload()` function. See http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/session.html

Comment: i.e. something like `session = getDefaultReactiveDomain();  
      session$reload()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will have to see a complete code to be able to help you. See if these will help you. Have fun

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


dat = data.frame(id = c("d","a","c","b"), a = c(1,2,3,4), b = c(6,7,8,9))

header <- dashboardHeader(

)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.content-wrapper { height: 1500px !important;}'))),
  sidebarMenu (
    menuItem("A", tabName = "d1"),
    menuItem("B", tabName = "d2"),
    menuItem("C", tabName = "d3")
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(

  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "d1",
            box(title = "AAA",
                actionButton("refreshTab1_id", "Refresh Tab 1"),
                actionButton("sortTable1_id", "Sort Table 1"),
                DT::dataTableOutput("table_for_tab_1", width = "100%"))
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = "d2",
             box(title = "BBB",
                actionButton("refreshTab2_id", "Refresh Tab 2"),
                actionButton("sortTable2_id", "Sort Table 2"),
                DT::dataTableOutput("table_for_tab_2", width = "100%"))
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = "d3",
            box(title = "CCC",
                actionButton("refreshTab3_id", "Refresh Tab 3"),
                actionButton("sortTable3_id", "Sort Table 3"),
                DT::dataTableOutput("table_for_tab_3", width = "100%"))
    )
  )
)

# UI
ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {


    observe({

        if (input$sortTable1_id || input$sortTable2_id || input$sortTable3_id) {
            dat_1 = dat %>% dplyr::arrange(id)
        } else {
            dat_1 = dat
        }

        output$table_for_tab_1 <- output$table_for_tab_2 <- output$table_for_tab_3 <- DT::renderDataTable({ 

            DT::datatable(dat_1, 
                    filter = 'bottom', 
                    selection = "single",
                    colnames = c("Id", "A", "B"),
                    options = list(pageLength = 10,
                                    autoWidth = TRUE#,
                                    # columnDefs = list(list(targets = 9, 
                                    #                        visible = FALSE))
                    )
            )
        })
    })

    observe({
        if (input$refreshTab1_id || input$refreshTab2_id || input$refreshTab3_id) {
            session$reload()
        }
    })

}

# Shiny dashboard
shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```