# Page Refresh Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to include a button in my shiny app that restarts the shiny session (the purpose being to reset the value of all inputs & action buttons). I am aware that shiny has the `session$reset()` function, and that the package `shinyjs` includes the `reset()` and `refresh()` functions for this purpose.

These options are working to refresh the page, but when I use them (or when I hit refresh manually), the formatting of my app becomes lost. Here are sample code and images illustrating the problem.

```
library(rhandsontable)

data = matrix(rnorm(10*10,mean=0,sd=1), 10, 10) 

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel('Patient Search v2.0'),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput('search', 'Search')
    ),

    mainPanel(
      rHandsontableOutput('data')
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  df = data
  output$data <- renderRHandsontable({rhandsontable(df)})

  session$onSessionEnded(stopApp)
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just press `F5` to refresh the page

Comment: Same issue when I press `F5`. I'm on a Mac if that helps.

Comment: Can really help you without some reproducible example

Comment: Have a look to [that topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34142841/page-refresh-button-in-r-shiny)

Comment: @PorkChop The issue occurs in any Shiny app that I run. I don't think it's a problem with Shiny because of that. When I'm running any Shiny app locally, when I refresh the page, it loses the regular format of the shiny app, as shown in my pictures above. This occurs when I hit 'refresh' when I run the app in RStudio as well. Would you have any ideas as to how to prevent this? Thank you very much.

Comment: I still need you to provide some code

Comment: It happens with nearly every shiny app. I just added code to make this reproducible.

Comment: remove `session$onSessionEnded(stopApp)`

Comment: That's it -- thank you very much.