# Make all users who have logged into Shiny-Server reload without resigning in

Tags: shiny, reload

I have a number of individuals who log into a shiny-server application where they all interact. After the app stops, I load another application, they each click ``reload'', and they all interact on the new application.

If someone clicks ``reload'' early, then everyone needs to re sign in. Is there any way to avoid this. I'd like to just regenerate shiny's default reload-page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how your `reaload` works as you havent posted any code, however you can force `F5` page refresh like so. parts of the code example are taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34142841/page-refresh-button-in-r-shiny)`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

jscode <- "shinyjs.reload = function() { window.location.reload(true); }"

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  extendShinyjs(text = jscode),
  textInput("text", "Text"),
  actionButton("reload", "Refresh app")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$reload, {
    js$reload();
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```