# Shiny - how to reset/ refresh the form?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

How can I refresh or reset the ui/ form in Shiny?

I have this button in ui.R:

```
actionButton("resetInput", "Reset inputs")
```

What should I do in the server.R to reset the form?

```
observeEvent(input$resetInput, {
   // refresh or reset the form      
})
```

I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30852356/add-a-page-refresh-button-by-using-r-shiny), but I get this error:

```
Warning: Error in library: there is no package called ‘shinyjs’
```

Does this package really exist?

Any better way of doing it without installing new packages?

Comment: The package does exist [here is a link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinyjs/index.html). I have just installed it on my machine using `install.packages("shinyjs")`. Are you using the latest version of R?

Comment: @MichaelBird yes I am. `R version 3.4.0` does it need the latest version R?

Comment: According to CRAN it needs R >3.1.0 so that's not the issue. The error suggests it is a library issue, other than that, I don't know.

Comment: alternatively you can use `updateSelectInput` to reset values after `actionbutton` trigger

Comment: @parth any example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put

```
library(shinyjs)
```

above your server definition, which is missing in the example you are referring to.

So:

```
library(shinyjs)
library(shiny)
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    div(
      id = "form",
      textInput("text", "Text", ""),
      selectInput("select", "Select", 1:5),
      actionButton("refresh", "Refresh")
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$refresh, {
      shinyjs::reset("form")
    })
  }
))
```

I will modify the answer you are referring to to also include the library call. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: No problem! Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your issue, thanks!