# how to clear input file after clicking 'cancel'? it works in explorer and in chrome is not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, file-io

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClLp4.png)

after i click 'Cancel' the file is still stuck there.
in explorer it works but in chrome i could not find any way to clear the input file.
the code is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzno5.png)
Please any help!!

Here is my code :

```
var AddFileWindow = $('#AddFileWindow').kendoWindow({
    title: 'Add File',
    visible: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 440,
    height: 450,
    resizable: false,
    actions: [
        "Close"
    ],
    activate: function () {
        $('#AddFileWindow').show();
    },
    close: function (e) {
        clearAddFileWindow();
    }
}).data('kendoWindow');

    function clearAddFileWindow() {
         var fileInput = $('#frame-files');
         fileInput.replaceWith(fileInput.val(''));
         $("#machine-file").data("kendoDropDownList").select(0);
         $("#material-file").data("kendoDropDownList").select(0);

         document.getElementById("material-group").style.display = "none";
         document.getElementById("alert").style.display = "none";
         document.getElementById("Notes-file").value = ""; 
        }

    <div id="AddFileWindow" style="display:none;">
                <div class='k-edit-label'>
                    <div class="form-horizontal form-widgets col-sm-10" style="margin-left:15px;">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="fileinput fileinput-new input-group" data-provides="fileinput" style="margin-top:10px">
                                <div class="form-control"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o fileinput-exists"></i> <span class="fileinput-filename"></span></div>
                                <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-primary btn-file">
                                    <span class="fileinput-new">Select file</span><span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span>
                                    <input id="frame-files" style="height:70px" type="file" name="...">
                                </span>
                                <a href="#" class="input-group-addon btn btn-primary fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: pls show your code

Comment: edit your question and post code in it

Comment: @user4810410 Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43189075/edit) your question and put the code there (And if possible, provide your HTML too)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to reset <input type = "file">](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549241/how-to-reset-input-type-file)

Comment: Works for me. Just call the function: https://jsfiddle.net/oopsduou/

Comment: but 'clearAddFileWindow' calls when you click on 'Cancel' ' it's not working for me. I edited my question