# Angular2: How to change selected file name to 'No file chosen'?

Tags: html, angular

I am using `html` file upload.

```
<input type="file" name="filedata" class="form-control" #file/>
```

After selection of file, file name showing in screen/UI.

```
<button pButton type="button" icon="fa-check" class="form-control" 
(click)="uploadFileByRest();" label="Upload"></button>
```

I am using upload button for uploading that file to Alfresco. On clicking on `upload` button I need to empty the file selected. Need to change file name showing to "No file chosen", which is showing before selecting file. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the value to an empty string should do that according to [how to reset <input type = "file">](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549241/how-to-reset-input-type-file)

```
<button pButton type="button" icon="fa-check" class="form-control" 
    (click)="uploadFileByRest();file.value = ''" 
    [disabled]="!isFileSelected" label="Upload"></button>
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I do this in component?

Comment: What component? Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: Angular2 component I am asking. You told fix in html. Good. I am coding in Angular 2. Can I do that value = '' in angular component?

Comment: Why should it not work ;). Just put the html it in your template or in a template file when you are using a templateUrl.

Comment: You mean it TypeScript code. The HTML template of a component is part of the component, this was confusing me. You can do it in code as well. You need a reference to `#file`. You can do it by passing it in `(click)="uploadFileByRest(file)"` and then in `uploadFileByRest(file) { ...; file.value = ''; }`, or using `@ViewChild('file') file:ElementRef,` and then in code `this.file.nativeElement.value = '';`.