# How to reset <input type = “file”> in AngularJS ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am prompting for a file name in an `ng-repeat` loop:

```
<tr ng-repeat="candidate in candidates.details">
    <td style="text-align:left"><input type="text" ng-model="candidate.name" placeholder="Candidate's name" autofocus ng-change="CandiateNameOrDescriptionChanged()" /></td>              

==> <td style="text-align:left"><input type="file" accept=".doc,.docx,.pdf"  id="csvFileSelector" file-change handler="CvSelected(candidate, files)"></td>                                          

    <td style="text-align:left"><textarea ng-model="candidate.description" placeholder="Descriptive text" ng-change="CandiateNameOrDescriptionChanged()" ></textarea></td>                                          
    <td style="text-align:left"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-success" style="margin-left:10%" ng-disabled="candidate.name=='' || candidate.cv==''" ng-click="DeleteCandidate($event, candidate)">Delete</button></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

My AngularJs handler for file selection checks for file extension being doc, docx or pdf and, if not, shows an alert.

I would also like it to reset the selected file name, showing it as blank.

[This question](http://%09%3Ctr%20ng-repeat=%22candidate%20in%20candidates.details%22%3E%20%09%09%3Ctd%20style=%22text-align:left%22%3E%3Cinput%20type=%22text%22%20ng-model=%22candidate.name%22%20placeholder=%22Candidate's%20name%22%20autofocus%20ng-change=%22CandiateNameOrDescriptionChanged()%22%20/%3E%3C/td%3E%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%20%09%09%3Ctd%20style=%22text-align:left%22%3E%3Cinput%20type=%22file%22%20accept=%22.doc,.docx,.pdf%22%20%20id=%22csvFileSelector%22%20file-change%20handler=%22CvSelected(candidate,%20files)%22%3E%3C/td%3E%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%20%09%09%3Ctd%20style=%22text-align:left%22%3E%3Ctextarea%20ng-model=%22candidate.description%22%20placeholder=%22Descriptive%20text%22%20ng-change=%22CandiateNameOrDescriptionChanged()%22%20%3E%3C/textarea%3E%3C/td%3E%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%20%09%09%3Ctd%20style=%22text-align:left%22%3E%3Cbutton%20type=%22button%22%20class=%22btn%20btn-outline%20btn-success%22%20style=%22margin-left:10%25%22%20ng-disabled=%22candidate.name==''%20%7C%7C%20candidate.cv==''%22%20ng-click=%22DeleteCandidate($event,%20candidate)%22%3EDelete%3C/button%3E%3C/td%3E%20%09%09%3Ctd%3E %3C/td%3E%20%09%3C/tr%3E%09%09%09%09%09%09%09https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549241/how-to-reset-input-type-file) shows how to do it, ***but*** it clears ***all*** input file names.

How can I clear only the one with the invalid extension (it is always the last)?

I am thinking of adding an element Id, based on some loop index (unless I can directly address the last such input), but am unsure of quite how to go about it.

Comment: Just add a name/id attribute to the input with an index, then pass that index to the handler function and clear it there. Something like `name='fileInput_x'` where x is the index.

Comment: And, them what? How would I clear the input field based on that?

Comment: With a javascript/jquery selector, setting its value to null or "'.

Comment: But, I am not a JQ/Jquery guy, just a smattering of Angular. Can you post a line of code to do so? Please, feel free to add an answer, with some sample code. Thanks

Comment: `document.getElementsByName("yourElementNameHere")[0].value='valueHere'`

Comment: Aaargh!!! So simple. Yup, even I could code that.