# Remote image upload performs different than development server

Tags: python, django, nginx, amazon-s3

My local development and live development server have the exact same code and database (all static/media files upload to s3 storage).

I have a `Post` model with an `image` field. My Post has an image upload field which uploads via AJAX to my s3 storage. In both my local and live server, the image successfully uploads and the url of that image in my s3 bucket is saved. So when I submit the Post in my local server, it doesn't upload again, I just point to the URL when I render the image.

However, my remote server doesn't do this. After I have uploaded the image via AJAX, when I submit the Post form, it then submits the image *again* (it shows the upload progression on my browser - 3%, 5%, 10% etc...).

Any idea why this happens? My code is here:

models

```
class Post(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
```

views

```
def post(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        form_post = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form_post.is_valid():
            instance = form_post.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            ...
            if instance.image:
                instance.imageURL = "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/media/%s" % filename
                instance.image = None #this prevents re-upload upon form submission

            instance.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            form_post = PostForm()

        context = {
            'form_post': form_post,
        }

        return render(request, 'post/post.html', context)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/accounts/signup/")
```

ajax view

```
def upload_image(request):
    random_filename = request.POST.get('random_filename')
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.FILES:
            img = request.FILES.get('image')


        session = boto3.Session(
            aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        )
        s3 = session.resource('s3')

        s3.Bucket('my-bucket').put_object(Key='media/%s' % random_filename, Body=img)
        return HttpResponse()

    else:
        return HttpResponse()
```

template

```
<input id="id_image" type="file" name="image" />
```

JS

```
$('input#id_image').on('change', function(e) {
    var file = $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();

    $('.add_file_div h3').hide();
    $('.add_file_label').css({
    'border-radius': '5px',
    'box-shadow': '5px',
    });
    var imagePath = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
    var random_filename = random_string();

    formData.append('image', file);
    formData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val());
    formData.append('random_filename', random_filename);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/upload_image/',
        data: formData,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(){
            console.log('SUCCESSFULLY UPLOADED');
            $('.add_file_label').css('opacity', '1');
            $('.add_file_label').css('background', 'url(' + imagePath + ') scroll no-repeat center/cover');
            $('.loading_spinner').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }
    });
    $('.add_file_label').css('background', 'url(' + imagePath + ') scroll no-repeat center/cover');
    $('.add_file_label').css('opacity', '0.4');
    $('.loading_spinner').css('visibility', 'visible');
    console.log(imagePath);

    $('.add_file_label').append('<input class="temp_s3_url" type="hidden" name="temp_s3_url">');
    $('.temp_s3_url').val(random_filename);
    $('input#id_imageURL').hide();
    $('#delete_preview_image').show();
});
```

PS: My nginx has `client_max_body_size 200m;` so that's not the problem

Comment: Pls post JS code.

Comment: Added in my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the same issue may be happening locally also. But when you are local the speed is fast enough for you to not see a upload progress bar. The thing is that you should clear your `file` field when you have had a success in the ajax upload

[how to reset <input type = "file">](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549241/how-to-reset-input-type-file)

so inside

```
success: function(){
  console.log('SUCCESSFULLY UPLOADED');
  $('.add_file_label').css('opacity', '1');
  $('.add_file_label').css('background', 'url(' + imagePath + ') scroll no-repeat center/cover');
  $('.loading_spinner').css('visibility', 'hidden');
}
```

You would reset the file element to make it a blank value, else it will get submitted with the form.

> Another option could be to just give the file input field a `id` and not a `name`. If there is no name attached to a `input` element it doesn't get submitted with a form

Comment: Thankyou removing the name prevented it from getting submitted with the form.