# How to remove uploaded attachment by clicking a button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

I'm implementing Asp.net Core to my project. In my create razor view, I have to upload file/s which works correctly. I also have a button with `id="attachmentremoval"` in the razor, by clicking on it, the attachment should be removed which I couldn't be successful to do it till now. Here is what I have tried till now.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form asp-action="Create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="form-group mt-3">
                <label for="files" class="custom-file-upload">
                    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>select file
                </label>
                <input id="files" name="AttachFile" type="file" style="display:none;">
                <span asp-validation-for="FileName" class="text-danger d-block mt-1"></span>
                <button id="attachmentremoval">
                    remove
                </button>
            </div>
   </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
<script>

    $('#files').change(function () {
        var arr = $('#file')[0];
        var i = $(this).prev('label').clone();
        var file = $('#files')[0].files[0].name;
        console.log('file:' + i);
        $(this).prev('label').text(file);


$("#attachmentremoval").on("click", function () {

                /*delete arr.files[0];*/
                $('.custom-file-upload').remove();
    });
    });

</script>
}
```

I appreciate if anyone could suggest me a solution to remove the attachment and again by clicking the lable it should attach a file.

Comment: You just need to clear that file name and file input ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to reset <input type = "file">](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549241/how-to-reset-input-type-file)

Answer (score 0):

Since the content of your `<form>` is just the `<input type="file" />`, You can just reset the form:

```js
function reset_form(){
   $('#form').trigger("reset");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
  <input id="files" type="file" /><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="reset_form()">Clear File</button>
</form>
```

Or you can set the `value` to ""

```js
function clear_files(){
   $('#files').val("");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
  <input id="files" type="file" /><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="clear_files()">Clear File</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo:

View:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form asp-action="Create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="form-group mt-3">
                <label for="files" class="custom-file-upload" id="fileslable">
                    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>select file
                </label>
                <input id="files" name="AttachFile" type="file" style="display:none;">
                <span asp-validation-for="FileName" class="text-danger d-block mt-1"></span>
                <input id="attachmentremoval" type="button" value="remove"/>
            </div>
   </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
  @section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    <script>
        $("#attachmentremoval").on("click", function () {
            document.getElementById("files").value = null;
            document.getElementById("fileslable").innerHTML = '\n            <i class=\"fa fa-cloud-upload\"></i>select files\n';
        });
        $('#files').change(function () {
            var arr = $('#file')[0];
            var i = $(this).prev('label').clone();
            var file = $('#files')[0].files[0].name;
            console.log('file:' + i);
            $(this).prev('label').text(file);
        });

    </script>
}
```

result:
[image]