# JavaScript - Load a file twice in a row

Tags: javascript

Good day,

I have the following code to load a ".TXT" file into a web page

```js
function load(event) {
  let fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = function() {
    let load0 = JSON.parse(fr.result);
    console.log(load0);
    console.log("Ready!");
  };
  fr.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
}

function loadInput(event) {
  document.getElementById("loadInputButton").click();
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input type="button" onclick="loadInput(event)" />
  <input id="loadInputButton" type="file" accept="text" onchange="load(event)" />
</body>

</html>
```

It works fine but only once. After I once load the file it will not work anymore. I try to load the same file again but the function produces nothing.

May I ask for your help solving it?

Thank you,
Eugene

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/j5ek3ynz/1/

Comment: @Barmar Does it work multiple times?

Comment: Yes. When I said "works fine" I meant it doesn't have the problem you describe. Does it work for you?

Comment: @Barmar No, I extracted the whole code into a new HTML file. It does not load the file twice for me. I must be doing something wrongly.

Comment: But what if you just run the code from jsfiddle? When it doesn't work, do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: OK, I can reproduce with the updated code you posted. So it has something to do with emulating clicks, which wasn't in the original question.

Comment: @Barmar I am actually not familiar to jsfiddle. But I figured it out. The function is called when the <input> with id = "loadInputButton" is changed in value. But if I load the same file with the same name the function does not fire.

Comment: Right. `onchange` only fires when the value changes.

Comment: @Barmar Do you happen to know how to clear the <input type = "file"> loaded file name?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549241/how-to-reset-input-type-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear the value of the input after using it, so that the `change` event will fire when you select the same file.

```js
function load(event) {
  let fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = function() {
    let load0 = JSON.parse(fr.result);
    console.log(load0);
    console.log("Ready!");
    event.target.value = '';
  };
  fr.readAsText(event.target.files[0])
}

function loadInput(event) {
  document.getElementById("loadInputButton").click();
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input type="button" onclick="loadInput(event)" />
  <input id="loadInputButton" type="file" accept="text" onchange="load(event)" />
</body>

</html>
```