# how to remove a file from a file input in laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, image, file, input

I have a lot of input type file in my view form, so I want to make when I selected a wrong file then i can remove the file with click on a button then the file that have been selected will be removed and only affected to that input file not to another input file, I don't know how to do it

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617738/how-to-clear-file-input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617738/how-to-clear-file-input). You can also check the comments links, I think they could be useful

Comment: thank you, i'll try to check it