# Attach file in php and inserting in a database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

this is a normal HTML method of attaching a file.

form enctype=`<"multipart/form-data" action="savefile.php" method="POST" name="myform">`

Send this file:

```
 input name="myfile" type="file" onchange="document.forms['myform'].submit() ;" 
            
</form>
```

**savefile.php**

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],

"upload/" . $_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);

echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
```

it works perfectly, my difficulty is that when I attach a file and it sends when I refresh the page, the file I attached still remains in the attachment,  how can I clear it so it shows "No chosen file"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect the user with

```
 header("Location: yourpage.php");
```

Also, submitting your form that way might not work on every browser.

Comment: thanks very much, i have tried using this method but i failed in the past, seen that i have no other option

Comment: i have a session variable called **$_SESSION['UserTO']** i would like to take along this session variable for example   header('Location: http://localhost/chat1/chat.php'$usernameto=$_SESSION['UserTO'];); but it gives me some errors, is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="myfile" type="file" onchange="document.forms['myform'].submit() ;" />
```

And JAVASCRIPT

```
var myInput = $("#input[name='myfile']");       

function resetInput(){       
    myInput.replaceWith( myInput.val('').clone( true ) );
};
```

Call `resetInput()` after the upload.

Ripped and adapted [From this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery)