# How to delete the value of an "input type=file"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to know how to delete the value of an **input type file** with Jquery.

More precisely what I call the value is when you upload a file from this input, but you haven't send the form.

I hope i'm understandable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery

Comment: Remove the element, and replace it. Otherwise, you can try setting the `value` property as `""`, but that isn't compatible in older IE browsers I think.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have a jsfiddle that you can demonstrate your problem with?

Comment: You could trigger the form's reset event. `form.reset()`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('input').val("");

});
```

Comment: Doesn't work in IE8.

Comment: i'm do it on my react project, and it works nicely