# JS for clearing <input type = "file"> selections

Tags: javascript, html, html5-filesystem

Once the user chooses the file, I have a condition using html5 file api to check if the file size exceeds a 1mb.

```
function handleLimit(evt) {
   var files = evt.target.files; 
   f = files[0];
   console.log(f.size);
   if (f.size > 1048576) {
          /*JS for clearing form*/
   }
}
```

What would be the script I would want to run on my input tag to clear/ force the client to choose another file it once the handler knows that file is exceeding a certain size?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery should get you there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 var _fileuploadcontrolId = document.getElementById("id");
            _fileuploadcontrolId.value = "";
            _fileuploadcontrolId.focus();
```

Comment: Perfect. I like your use of focus() for UX.

Comment: @Emanegux i dont know why some people behave like this.With out any comment giving downvote