# jQuery Example: Reseting an input file element in case of non-allowed file-extensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone, reset, file-io

If someone tries to upload a file with a non-allowed file-extension, this input-file-element should get "reseted".

That is the input-file-element

```
<input type="file" id="image1">
```

These are the corresponding jQuery-statements (document is ready) and I get "TypeError: myElement.clone is not a function" (while I am trying this solution here: [Clearing <input type='file' /> using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery))

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#image1').change(function(event) {
        checkExtensions(this.files[0].name, $(this).get());
    });

    function checkExtensions (fileName, element) {

        var myElement = element;
        var allowedExtensions = new Array ('pdf','gif','jpg','png');
        var currentExtension = fileName.split('.').pop();

        if ($.inArray (currentExtension, allowedExtensions) > -1) {
            // everythins is OK, further instructions take place
        }   else {
            // reset the file input element
            myElement.replaceWith( myElement = myElement.clone( true ) );
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the native DOM element to your function instead of the jQuery object containing the element. Native DOM elements do not have the function `clone()` (or `replaceWith` either). Try this instead:

```
$('#image1').change(function(event) {
    checkExtensions(this.files[0].name, $(this)); // note, I removed .get()
});

function checkExtensions (fileName, $element) {
    var allowedExtensions = new Array ('pdf','gif','jpg','png');
    var currentExtension = fileName.split('.').pop();

    if ($.inArray (currentExtension, allowedExtensions) > -1) {
        // everything is OK, further instructions take place
    }   else {
        // reset the file input element        
        $element.replaceWith($element.clone(true).val(''));
    }
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/66fGx/)

Comment: May be a last question in this regard: what does $ do in $element exactly?

Comment: @E2B it doesn't do anything. It's just a naming convention to show that that variable holds a jQuery object.

Comment: But it does not work without "$" or do I make an another mistake?

Comment: That sounds like a mistake elsewhere, as the `$` makes no difference to the logic