# how to delete file if width != 829 px And height != 90 px

Tags: php, jquery

how to delete file from input type="file" if width != 829 px And height != 90 px

i use `this.value=""` but not work , How can i do ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    $("#image_1").change(function(e) {
        var image_1, img;
        if ((image_1 = this.files[0])) {
            img = new Image();
            img.onload = function() {
                if ((this.width != '728') && (this.height != '90'))
                {
                alert("not width 728 px and height 90 px.");
                this.value=""
                }
            };
            img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(image_1);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery):

```
function resetFormElement(e) {
  e.wrap('<form>').closest('form').get(0).reset();
  e.unwrap();
}​

var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
$("#image_1").change(function(e) {
    var image_1, img;
    if ((image_1 = this.files[0])) {
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            if ((this.width != '728') && (this.height != '90'))
            {
            alert("not width 728 px and height 90 px.");
            resetFormElement($(this));
            }
        };
        img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(image_1);
    }
});
```