# How to remove a tag using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `<div>` tag

```
         <ul id="userpic" class="user pic">
           <im class="pict"/>
              Picture preview
         </ul>

          <div id="showpicname">
               <div id="delpc"></div>
               <div id="picnam"></div>
          </div>
```

and a jQuery function to remove `delpc` and `picnam`:

```
$("#delpc").click(function () {
    $(".pict").hide().fade(slow);
    $("#delpc").hide().fade(slow);
    $("#picnam").hide().fade(slow);
});

<input id="browse"  type="file" name="upl"  onchange="preview(this)" accept="image/*"/>
```

I am able to hide pict but unable to hide picnam and delpc and deselect the file selected by id="browse"

What am I doing wrong here? I am using the same method as hiding the class=pict img.

I have tried all the possible ways but no luck.

Help me out here please.

Thanks

Comment: `$().fade` does not exist, your script throws when attempting to call it for the first time. Check the JS console.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté thanks a lot buddy, that works, I have removed the fade, but how to deselect the selected file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   $("#delpc").click(function () {
        $(".pict").fadeOut("slow", function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });
        $("#delpc").fadeOut("slow", function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });
        $("#picnam").fadeOut("slow", function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });

    });
```

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery) for resetting the file browser

Comment: Thanks this one is nice, but I was wondering how to deselect the selected file by the <input id="browse"> tag, should I remove the file from the fake path ? or there is any other efficient way ?

Answer (score 1):

See this fiddle:

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k4F6H/8/)

And here goes the code:

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#delpc").click(function () {
         $(".pict").fadeOut("slow");
         $("#delpc").fadeOut("slow");
         $("#picnam").fadeOut("slow");

    });
});
```

**OR** // no need to use both hide and fadeout

```
$(function() {
    $("#delpc").click(function () {
         $(".pict").hide();
         $("#delpc").hide();
         $("#picnam").hide();

    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
     <ul id="userpic" class="user pic">
       <im class="pict"/>
          Picture preview
     </ul>

      <div id="showpicname">
           <div id="delpc">delete</div>
           <div id="picnam">picnam</div>
      </div>
     <input id="browse"  type="file" name="upl"  onchange="preview(this)" accept="image/*"/>
```

Comment: `hide()` is executed before the `fadeOut()`. Why execute both these? Either hide it instantly, or fade it out.

Comment: You're still hiding them before the `fadeOut()`is completed. After the fadeOut is completed, the elements are hidden anyway, so the `hide()` is obsolete. Even though it is in OP original code. Just go with
http://jsfiddle.net/k4F6H/7/

Answer (score 1):

You should be using **[.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)**.You will not even need to hide it.:

```
$(".pict").fadeOut('slow');
$("#delpc").fadeOut('slow');
$("#picnam").fadeOut('slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

`fade` should be `fadeOut`

Change

```
$("#delpc").hide().fade(slow);
$("#picnam").hide().fade(slow);
```

to

```
$("#delpc").hide().fadeOut("slow");
$("#picnam").hide().fadeOut("slow");
```

Comment: You do not need hide. fadeOut eventually hides the element.