# Clear/Reset file input on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to clear a file upload input field when the page loads. I have looked at 10-15 various ways to do this via stackoverflow, however every suggestion includes a reset button where I want to clear it on page load so that it is reset/cleared if a user clicks the back button on their browser.

I am currently using this code to reset the entire form, it works well for all of the dropdowns however it does not clear the file input field

```
function init() {
    // Clear forms here
    //reset inputs
$('#upload_form').trigger("reset");
//reset upload form

}

window.onload = init;
```

From my researh this seems to have the most upvotes from the community [Clearing <input type='file' /> using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery)

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for that:

```
function init() {
  document.getElementById("upload_form").reset();
}

window.onload = init;
```

Comment: It does work on my computer, if the input is in a `<form>`: http://jsfiddle.net/BZjfL/2/

Answer (score 2):

One way to reset the file input type field is to replace it with a new one:

```
function reset() {
    var input = document.querySelector('.file-input');
    var newInput = input.cloneNode(true);
    input.parentNode.replaceChild(newInput, input);
}
```

Example

**http://jsfiddle.net/d25nV/**

Comment: There's no need to alter the DOM for that.

Comment: Not me: although it's unnecessarily complex, it's not wrong.