# Jquery detect multiple files change in Safari

Tags: jquery

The code below is taken from [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SrABk/) fiddle.

```
$('#upload').change(function(){
   alert();

});

<input type='file' id='upload' name='image[]' multiple='multiple' />
```

I have an input file use jquery detect when user change the files but I have trouble because its multiple files upload in Safari 5.1

ex.
3 files - 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg

If the user clicks **1.jpg** first, then changes his mind, clicks **1.jpg** & **2.jpg**, it will not works because **1.jpg** didn't change,

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: if i click 1.jpg it alert, but I click upload again and select 1.jpg, 2.jpg, it wont works, because 1.jpg is not change

Comment: you mean for the first time I select 3 images. later decide to select two of them but event doesn't fire ?

Comment: no first time i select 1 image, later i decide select 2, because previous image is repeat therefor it wont works

Comment: its works for me. first time i select 1.jpg alert came. later i selected 2.jpg and 3.jpg still worked

Comment: change doesn't fire only if you select same set of images or same single image

Comment: sorry i should add, its not work in safari 5.1
http://jsfiddle.net/DL9Sk/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery