# How do I 'unselect' a selected file?

Tags: angularjs, angular-file-upload

I'm using this to allow the user to select and upload a file:

```
<input id="fileInput" type="file" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)">
```

This correctly show:

[image]

When user clicks 'Upload', I upload the file.

When the user clicks 'Remove', how do I clear out the file name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clearing <input type='file' /> using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery)

Comment: The solution in the link does not work @farhatmihalko

Comment: Thanks farhatmihalko.  I was looking for an angular way of doing it.  If there isn't, I can use this.

Comment: Indeed doesn't work on IE10 (works in IE11). Otherwise, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply clear the value of the file input element:

```
document.getElementById('remove').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.getElementById('fileInput').value = ''
});
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/raam86/dAQVM/489/)

Comment: @Jason this is not an angular way, in angular you should not touch the dom elements directly this way. instead you can use `angular.element()` with use of `jqLite` event binding, see the answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25443443/1059101

Comment: Hi Jai, why isn't this the angular way? they do offer an api for dom manipulation buy why use it. You should that the same happens behind the scenes with less overhead

Answer (score 5):

It should be more angular way like this with `angular.element(element)`:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('remove')).on('click', function(){
    angular.element(document.getElementById('fileInput')).val('');
});
```

#### [Plunkr Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/9dTc8edXINxVib2VL2J8?p=preview)

---

### From the docs usage:

```
angular.element(element);
```

where `angular.element()` creates a jQuery object and this `(element)` in the braces is the *HTML string or DOMElement to be wrapped into jQuery*.

Answer (score 0):

Googling lead me here, so to help others you can also do this using straight jQuery:

```js
$("#clear").on("click", function() {
  $("#fileInput").val("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="fileInput" />
<button id="clear">Clear</button>
```

Comment: OP asked question related to angularjs. How google lead you here?