# How to clear or empty input:file when cloned?

Tags: jquery

- How could I clear or empty the input type file after I clone the source for it has already a file selected before. I already applied this approach [Clearing <input type='file' /> using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery) seems not working on my set up.

By the way the code is wrap with form element.

== source ==

```
var source = $( '#table-wrapper' ),
        clone = source.clone( true ),
        count = clone.length;

<div id="table-wrapper">
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td></td>
     </tr>
   </table>
   <p class="pdf-add-row"><input id="pdf" type="file"/></p>
</div>
```

== clone ==

```
<div id="table-wrapper-1">
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td></td>
     </tr>
   </table>
   <p class="pdf-add-row"><input id="pdf-1" type="file"/></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it inside a form element?

Comment: Yes it is inside the form element. See edited code above.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lyzr751b/1/

Comment: The file removed by me when i click the clone button. (Chrome) But not on firefox i see

Comment: Thanks @ArunPJohny, but on my set up it doesn't work. After I clone the source, id's will only have a '-1' format to separate from the source which the structure is pretty the same as the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$('button').click(function () {
    var source = $( '#table-wrapper' ),
        clone = source.clone( true ),
        count = clone.length;

    clone.find('input').val('');

    clone.appendTo('#result')
})
```

Comment: You can actually chain it like this: source.clone( true ).find('input').val('')

Comment: @jaytemp no... then `clone` will refer to the `input` element not the cloned container

Comment: You could chain it like this: `source.clone(true).find('input').val('').end()`. But i don't like it. We can chain almost anything.

Answer (score 1):

Do this..

```
clone = source.clone( true ).find('input').val('')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var source = $('#table-wrapper'),
    clone = source.clone(true),
    count = clone.length;

  //append the clone to a temp form so that it can be restted
  $('<form />').append(clone)[0].reset();

  clone.appendTo('#result')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table-wrapper">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p class="pdf-add-row">
    <input id="pdf-1" type="file" />
  </p>
</div>
<button>Clone</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lyzr751b/)