# Not able to reset File Upload control value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.file, new { type = "file", id = "policyFile", @class = "ace-file-input" })

$('#policyFile').ace_file_input({
    no_file: 'No File ...',
    btn_choose: 'Choose',
    btn_change: 'Change',
    droppable: false,
    onchange: null,
    thumbnail: false
});
```

Now i am using  `$("#policyFile").val("");` but not reset the control value

Comment: see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers don't allow modifications or clear operations to be performed on the file type input for security reasons. The trick is to clone the control.

```
var control = $("#policyFile");
control.replaceWith( control = control.clone( true ) );
```

The above code will replace your control with a replica of it. This will create a new file type input with the same attributes in place of already existing file input. Hope this helps. Let me know if it worked out.