# how to clear an input file field in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In jquery I am trying to clear a field, but if I do, it throws an error. It does make the field go empty, but also throws an error. How can I fix that?

Thanks

HTML

```
<input name="file" type="file" accept="image/*">
```

JS

```
var input = $("#profile-edit-form").find("input[name=file]");
var fileName = input.val();

if(fileName) { // returns true if the string is not empty
    input.replaceWith(input.val('').clone(true));
}
```

ERROR

```
NotFoundError: Node was not found                  
-jquery.min.js:3:0
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the error or provide more context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you trying to do a `clone`?

Just doing this should clear the field:

```
input.val('');
```

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate:

http://jsfiddle.net/kcbc701c/

Edit:

Yeah, there may be issues with the above in older browsers, it'd be worth testing, but for me that works in modern browsers, whereas the other option you stated doesn't work in firefox...

here's a fiddle with both so you can test:  http://jsfiddle.net/frrc7bLy/

Comment: yes, but the error seems to be at the `find()` part.

Comment: Why use `find()` like that instead of assigning the element an ID?

Comment: @northkildonan No, jQuery is so kind,  normally it handles empty collections without throwing any error.

Comment: Lots of pages say to do what I did, like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Although jQuery might be forgiving enough to handle it, the documented format is:

```
var input = $("#profile-edit-form").find('input[name="file"]');
```

Note the quotes around "file" in the selector.

Comment: Well, _this_ and _that_ selector do the same thing.

Comment: So you're saying that jQuery IS forgiving in that respect?

Comment: That's not an invalid selector, both are valid. Quotations are useful when the attribute's value can break the selector/confuse the jQuery's selector engine. An example: `'input[name="group[withBrackets]"]'`.