# Removing/Clearing all selected files via the File Input button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the input element in HTML with the file type option, IE: `<input type="file" />` with the option of allowing multiple files to be selected.

However, I'm wondering if there's a way to remove or clear all of the files that the user selected via the file type button though a click of a button.

Basically, here is what I have so far:

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" />
<input type="button" value="Clear all attachments" onclick="" />
```

I have no idea how to implement that second button.

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a trick: Redraw the HTML block! [Source](http://gusiev.com/2009/04/clear-upload-file-input-field/)

```
<div id="container">
   <input type="file" multiple="multiple" />
   <input type="button" value="Clear all attachments" onclick="clearSelection();" />
</div>

//Javascript
function clearSelection() {
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = document.getElementById("container").innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the id in the getElementById function be the id of the file input button?

Comment: Sorry. You need to surround with a container and redraw that. I updated my answer.