# php | Defend move_upload_file or delete files from input[type="file"] using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an input[type="file"] had multiple option. I made it preview function so that user can delete the image by clicking the button before submit. The images are deleted well on browser by remove() function however the problem is the values of input including the deleted images are posted when i submit. I don't know how to delete real value of input.

I've tried to figure it out to delete in the server side. 
This is the part of html code.

```
<div class="col-xs-4 vcenter from-group">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk" style="color:red;"></span><label for="inputScreenshots">스크린샷</label>
<p style="display:inline; padding-left:270px; color:red; font-size: 12px">* 이미지 사이즈 : 800 X 450</p>
<input type="file" id="inputScreenshots" name="inputScreenshots[]" class="form-control" accept="image/*" multiple>
<div id="filenameList" style="width : 400px">
    <div id="insertScreenshots" style="margin : 30px; position :relative;">
        <input type="hidden" name="screenshots_filename[]" value="<?=$screenshot_urls?>">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the php code where im trying to defend uploading images.

```
$ss_upload="false";
if (isset($_POST["del_screenshots"])){
// del_screenshots are images that deleted from client.
$ds_count = $_POST["del_screenshots"];
    foreach($ds_count as $del) {
        echo "<br/> del_screenshots : ".$del;
    }
}

$ss_count = sizeof($_FILES['inputScreenshots']['tmp_name']);
// ss_count is the size of all images including deleted images from input field.
echo "<br/>ss_cout : ". $ss_count;

for ($i = 0; $i < $ss_count; $i++) {
$tmpFilePath = $_FILES['inputScreenshots']['tmp_name'][$i];
$tmp_filename = $_FILES['inputScreenshots']['name'][$i];
// tmp_filename is the posted real file name.
echo "<br/> tmp_filename".$i. " : " .$tmp_filename;
//=========================================================================
for ($j = 0; $j < sizeof($ds_count); $j++) {
    // Compare all images name and deleted images name
    if (strcmp($ds_count[$j] ,  $tmp_filename) == 0)    {
        echo "<br/>".$ds_count[$j] . " == " . $tmp_filename . "==>  " ."true";
       // The $tmp_filename has to be deleted. not to be uploaded to server.
       // $tmp_filename = null; 
    }else {
        echo "<br/>".$ds_count[$j] . " == " . $tmp_filename . "==>  " ."false";
        // This files are okay to be uploaded to server.
    }
}
//=========================================================================
$ext = pathinfo($tmp_filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
//  $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['inputScreenshots']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
echo "<br/>". $i . " ext (pathinfo) : ". $ext;
if ($ext == "") {
    continue;
    $ss_upload="false";
}
$newFilePath = uniqid().".".$ext;
if ($screenshots != "") {
    $screenshots .= "+";
}
$screenshots .= $newFilePath;
// $screenshots has be uploaded to DB except the deleted images. (ex : uniqFileName.png + uniqFileName.png + .. )

    echo "<br/> 1) screenshots : ". $screenshots;
    move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $SS_PATH."/".$newFilePath);
    $ss_upload="true";
}
```

I want to defend uploading the deleted images but it is no matter to use unlink() in somewhere. The point is how cant i make the string except the deleted images.

=========================================================================
I suppose there is another way to do in jQuery but i have no idea.
I'll put the code below.

```
$("#inputScreenshots").change(function(){
    $("#filenameList div.notyet").remove();
    for(var i = 0, len = this.files.length; i < len; i++){
        var file = this.files[i];
        var fr = new FileReader();
        fr.onload = screenshots_processFile(file);
        fr.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
});

var screenshots_processFile = function screenshots_processFile(file) {
 return (function(file) {
 return function(e) {
     var div = document.createElement("div");
     $(div).addClass("notyet").css({
        margin: "30px",
        position: "relative"
      });
      var html = [,'<img src="" width="100%" id="tmp_screenshots">'
                 ,'<button type="button" class="close img-close" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'
                 ].join("");
      $(div).append(html);
      $(div).find("button").click(function() {
         alert("remove");
       //=========================================================== * TODO : remove the files in server!
        var targetDom = document.getElementById( "filenameList" );
        var targetInput = document.createElement("input");
        targetInput.setAttribute("name", "del_screenshots[]" );
        targetInput.setAttribute("type","hidden");
        targetDom.appendChild(targetInput);
        alert(file.name);
        targetInput.setAttribute("value", file.name);
       //===========================================================
         $(this).parent().remove();
      });
      $(div).find("img").attr("src", e.target.result);
      $("#filenameList").append(div);
    }
  })(file)
};
```

How can i do this? Does anyone have an idea?

**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

I solved it like this. I know my code is so dirty :-/

```
$ss_upload="false";
if (isset($_POST["del_screenshots"])){
$ds_count = $_POST["del_screenshots"];
foreach($ds_count as $del) {
    echo "<br/> del_screenshots : ".$del;
}
    //echo "<br/> << TEST >>"."<br/>ds_count[0] : " . $ds_count[0]  . "<br/>ds_count[1] : " . $ds_count[1] ;
}

$ss_count = sizeof($_FILES['inputScreenshots']['tmp_name']);
echo "<br/>ss_cout : ". $ss_count;

for ($i = 0; $i < $ss_count; $i++) {
$tmpFilePath = $_FILES['inputScreenshots']['tmp_name'][$i];
$tmp_filename = $_FILES['inputScreenshots']['name'][$i];
    echo "<br/> tmp_filename".$i. " : " .$tmp_filename;
    $ss_del_mode="false";
//=========================================================================


 if (isset($_POST["del_screenshots"])) {
for ($j = 0; $j < sizeof($ds_count); $j++) {
    if (strcmp($ds_count[$j] ,  $tmp_filename) == 0)    {
        echo "<br/>".$ds_count[$j] . " == " . $tmp_filename . "==>  " ."true";
        $ss_del_mode = "true";
    }
}
}
//=========================================================================
$ext = pathinfo($tmp_filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);


 //  $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['inputScreenshots']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

echo "<br/>". $i . " ext (pathinfo) : ". $ext;
if ($ext == "") {
    continue;
    $ss_upload="false";
}
if ($ss_del_mode == "true") {
    echo "<br/> ss_del_mode [[[[ " . $ss_del_mode. " ]]]]";
    $newFilePath = "";
} else {
    $newFilePath = uniqid().".".$ext;
    echo "<br/> ss_del_mode [[[[ " . $ss_del_mode. " ]]]]";
}
if ($screenshots != "") {
    if ($ss_del_mode != "true"){
        echo "<br/> ss_del_mode [[[[ " . $ss_del_mode. " ]]]]". "   --> screenshots";
        $screenshots .= "+";
    }
}
$screenshots .= $newFilePath;
echo "<br/> 1) screenshots (newFilePath) : ". $screenshots;
if ($newFilePath != "") {
    move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $SS_PATH."/".$newFilePath);
}
$ss_upload="true";
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clearing <input type='file' /> using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery)