# clone jquery input file was not clearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

With my current code I am able to clone entire div. But if the user attach any documents then the user click add more button the data are remain same on the cloned div.

This is the code I have so far below that isn't working. You can also see this on js fiddle: [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/546udj15/9/)

I have try with the following code `$(".custom-file-input").closest('form').trigger('reset'); But this was resetting the original div not the clone one. Some where I am lagging kindly please help me.

```
var count=0;
$(document).on("click", ".attch_add_button", function () {
    var $clone = $('.cloned-row4:eq(0)').clone();

    $clone.find('[id]').each(function(){this.id+=''});
    $clone.find('.btn_more').after("<input type='button' class='btn_right btn_less1' id='buttonless'/>")
    $clone.attr('id', "added"+(++count));
    $clone.find('.preview').hide();
    $clone.wrap('<form>');
    $clone.closest('form').trigger('reset');
    $clone.unwrap();

    $(this).parents('.medica_rpt').after($clone);
});


$(document).on('click', ".btn_less1", function (){
    var len = $('.cloned-row4').length;
    if(len>1){
        $(this).closest(".btn_less1").parents('.medica_rpt').remove();
    }
});
```

Here is the html code

```
<div class="medica_rpt cloned-row4" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1 col-md-2 col-lg-2 ctm_lft_mrpt">
            <label class="lbl_accep">Accepted ?</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 ctm_lft_mrpt">
            <label class="lbl_accep">Accepted by</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 ctm_lft_mrpt">
            <label class="lbl_accep">Accepted on</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 ctm_lft_mrpt">
            <label class="lbl_accepft">Document Remarks</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <div class="custom-file-input" id="custom-file-input">
                <input type="file" class="check">
                <input type="text" class="txt_field ctm_widt check" id="file_name" disabled placeholder="Attached File">
                <button class="cst_select ">
                    <i class="fa  fa-rotate-90">
                    </i> Attach
                </button>
            </div>
            <a href="#" target="_blank" class="preview">View</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1 col-md-2 col-lg-2 ctm_lft_mrpt">
            <input type="checkbox">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 ctm_lft_mrpt">
            <input type="text" class="smipt_Field" id="accpt_by" name="accpt_by" disabled/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 ctm_lft_mrpt">
            <input type="text" class="smipt_Field" id="accpt_on" name="accpt_on" disabled/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 ctm_lft_mrpt">
            <select class="slt_Field" id="txt_dcmRem" name="txt_dcmRem">
                <option value="" selected='selected'>&nbsp; </option>
                <option value="COLR">Coloured Copy Required</option>
                <option value="EXPR">Expired Document</option>
                <option value="INSF">Insufficient</option>
                <option value="INVD">Invalid Document</option>
                <option value="LOWR">Low Resolution</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 pull-right clear">
            <input type="button" class="btn_more btn_right attch_add_button"/>
            <!--<button class="btn_more btn_right attch_add_button"></button>-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Kindly help suggest me I am confused here.

Comment: you're better off using angularjs or knockout for these kinds of tasks

Comment: hi @andrew thanks for the suggestion but Here I want to use only on jquery

Comment: ok will i couldn't get your fiddle to work, it wouldn't let me attach a file. but what i'd suggest is taking a clone of the row on page load and store it in a variable. then when a new row is added clone the clone rather than the last row

Comment: kindly click the text field not on the attach button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are cloning form elements best work around for this is to reset the cloned form.

In the fiddle example there is no form at all, so, in case you are cloning some input fields but not the whole form you might need to wrap those input inside a form, reset that form, and then unwrap.

Your JS should end up similar to this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".attch_add_button", function () {
    var $clone = $('.cloned-row4:eq(0)').clone();
    $clone.find('[id]').each(function(){this.id+=''});
    $clone.find('.btn_more').after("<input type='button' class='btn_right btn_less1' id='buttonless'/>")
    $clone.attr('id', "added"+(++count));
    $clone.find('#custom-file-input').val('');

    $clone.wrap('<form>');
    $clone.closest('form').reset();
    $clone.unwrap();

    $(this).parents('.medica_rpt').after($clone);
});
```

You might want to check slipheed's answer on [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery) question

Comment: thanks for the help but I am getting an error $clone.closest(...).reset is not a function

Comment: try with: `$clone.closest('form').trigger('reset');`

Comment: one small request how to hide view link once the field is got reset

Comment: I don't understand, what needs to be hidden? could you make a fiddle recreating this specific issue for me please?

Comment: Thanks @Aramil I found the solution for that thanks for the help

Comment: Hi @Aramil, There was a huge problem with the current code when the user click addmore button in the clone div attachment was not working kindly please help me

Comment: I can't help you if I don't know whats happening :( please provide me with a working example that recreates your issue or edit the question with the new, relevant, code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89854/discussion-between-mahadevan-and-aramil-rey).