# How to Clean input file Bootstrap field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Person,

I have a page with **2 input text**  and **2 input file** when I get the ajax response, send clear the entire form as the code below, but only a field is not cleared the field:

[Here my page](http://williamvillar.com.br/Push_Novo/msg_big_pic.php)

```
<input class="fileUploadAudio" id="fileUploadAudio" name="fileUploadAudio" type="file"></span>
```

I believe we should have some conflict, I have done everything and I can not clear this blessed country.

PS: If you need I publish the page to take a look.

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Imagem para Push</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                       <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
                          <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
                             <img src="http://placehold.it/190x140/7761A7/ffffff" alt="...">
                          </div>
                          <div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px;"></div>
                          <div>
                             <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new">Selecionar imagem</span><span class="fileinput-exists">Alterar</span>
                             <input class="arquivo" id="arquivo" name="arquivo" type="file"></span>
                             <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remover</a>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Áudio para a campanha</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                       <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
                          <input name="..." value="" type="hidden">
                          <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new">Selecionar áudio</span>
                          <span class="fileinput-exists">Alterar</span>
                          <input class="fileUploadAudio" id="fileUploadAudio" name="fileUploadAudio" type="file"></span>
                          <span class="fileinput-filename"></span>
                          <a href="#" class="close fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput" style="float: none">×</a>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
```

In return I send ajax clear the form fields like this:

```
$(".formulario")[0].reset();
$(".formulario").get(0).reset();
$('#cancelButton').hide();
$("#fileUploadAudio").val("");
$('#submitButton').hide();
```

I have even tried to clear only the input file this way:

```
$('#fileUploadAudio').val('');
```

Comment: are you using any plugin/extension for file uploader ?

Comment: No, no plugin.
My code clear all fields except the file input field audio

Comment: $(".formulario")[0].reset();
 $(".formulario").get(0).reset();

Comment: Only problem on a file input, the other clean normally.

Comment: Personally, I just put a call CLEAR button.
To test do the following: select two files in 2 fileinput then click this button. ->http://williamvillar.com.br/Push_Novo/msg_big_pic.php

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/13351234/6383857

Comment: Hello friend, I had read this post until I did as told, but does not work. I've done everything and can not find the bug. In consumes the following error:
too much recursion
...sName&&b.getElementsByClassName)return G.apply(d,b.getElementsByClassName(f)),d}...
jquery.min.js (linha 2, col 6855)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to reset the whole form.

1. Change the outer `div` tag to `form`as followings:

   Replace

   `<div class="form-group">...</div>`

   with

   `<form class="form-group" id="formulario">...</form>`
2. Reset form using jQuery

   ```
   $("#formulario")[0].reset();
   ```

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo there it should be 
`$("#formulario")[0].reset();` instead of `$("#formulario)[0].reset();` - I missed the " character

Answer (score 0):

if native java script reset function is not working you need to trigger the reset function 
`$("#formulario").trigger("reset");`