# How to clear the img placeholder for choose image using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a form with fileupload.

```
<input class="file" type="file" name="files[]">
```

I am curently cloning the input, but if a file is choosen it also clones the choosen filinput, is there a way to clear the selected image?

script: `$('.fieldset-content_doc').first().clone().appendTo('.fieldset-clone_doc').find('.file').reset();`

fieldset-content_doc: holds the formvalues

Comment: How are you cloning it?

Comment: Does it happen in https://jsfiddle.net/7z1eu4ab/ too?

Comment: yes, seams it does.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Chrome 53. What's your browser?

Comment: im using firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the issue is only reproducible on Firefox. But, you can simply set the `value` property of the element to `null`:

```
$('.fieldset-content_doc')
    .first()
    .clone()
    .appendTo('.fieldset-clone_doc')
    .find('.file')
    .each(function() { this.value = null; });
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7z1eu4ab/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use reset() if field is not inside `<form>`.
You can clear input by wrapping element into form, reseting it and then unwrapping.

```
function resetFormElement(e) {
  e.wrap('<form>').closest('form').get(0).reset();
  e.unwrap();

  // Prevent form submission
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13351234/3581321

Answer (score 0):

In your script instead of `reset()` you can use `val('')`. Like this

```
$('.fieldset-content_doc').first().clone().appendTo('.fieldset-clone_doc').find('.file').val('');
```