# Change input with image after open image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code here :

```
<div id="tabs-2" class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-elements">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 fileContainer padding-box">
        <div class="pic-box">
          <div class="plus-box">xyz</div>
          <input type="file" accept="image/*">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 fileContainer padding-box">
        <div class="pic-box">
          <div class="plus-box">xyz</div>
          <input type="file" accept="image/*">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 fileContainer padding-box">
        <div class="pic-box">
          <div class="plus-box">xyz</div>
          <input type="file" accept="image/*">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 fileContainer padding-box">
        <div class="pic-box">
          <div class="plus-box">xyz</div>
          <input type="file" accept="image/*">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zctw030x/1/)

What I want is when i'm opening the image to change the content of the div with the image i'm opening... like a preview.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+preview+image

Comment: Not really like this..I want to put the preview instead of the input

Comment: hm..is not working

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/hrxnne9q/)

Please note that if you need to reuse the input field, you need to reset it or the change will not trigger if the same image is chosen

[Clearing <input type='file' /> using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery)

```js
$(function() {
  $("input[type=file]").on("change", function(e) {
    var output = $("<img/>", {
      src: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])
    });
    $(e.target).closest("div.pic-box").html(output)
  });
});
```

```css
.fileContainer {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.fileContainer [type=file] {
  cursor: inherit;
  display: block;
  font-size: 999px;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: right;
  top: 0;
}
.pic-box {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-top: 3%;
}
.plus-box {
  color: red;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  top: 30px;
}
.padding-box {
  padding-left: 5px !important;
  padding-right: 5px !important;
  padding-top: 10px !important;
}
.pic-box img { width:100% }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs-2" class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-elements">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 fileContainer padding-box">
        <div class="pic-box">
          <div class="plus-box">xyz</div>
          <input type="file" accept="image/*">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 fileContainer padding-box">
        <div class="pic-box">
          <div class="plus-box">xyz</div>
          <input type="file" accept="image/*">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 fileContainer padding-box">
        <div class="pic-box">
          <div class="plus-box">xyz</div>
          <input type="file" accept="image/*">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 fileContainer padding-box">
        <div class="pic-box">
          <div class="plus-box">xyz</div>
          <input type="file" accept="image/*">
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah..it's good here..but I want to have the height and width of the prev box (to be responsive)

Comment: There is nothing responsive in resizing the image on the client. But just have the css resize an image in a  padding-box or a pic-box depending on which div you fill

Comment: I want to where is <img/> to put style='width:100%' but it's not working

Comment: `.pic-box img { width:100% }`

Comment: You are welcome. Just don't call me _dude_, please :)