# How to clear files from <input type='file' /> using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input-type-file

There are several `<input type='file' />` fields in my file and there are no any html `form`s. I want to clear attached files from particular `<input type='file' />`. Not from the all fields. I have use `$('input').val("");` but it clears all the `<input type='file' />` fields. So how I clear the attached files from particular `<input type='file' />` field?

```js
var control = $("#mcontrol");

$("#clear").on("click", function() {
  $('input').val("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="mcontrol" /><br>
<input type="file" id="mcontrol2" />
<button id="clear">Clear</button>
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/isurufit/j2x7mcxk/)

Comment: Look here (using jquery): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery

Comment: also your fiddle, is missing a link to jQuery so it fails on the first `$`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clearing <input type='file' /> using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using JavaScript you can do that as follows.

`document.getElementById("#control").value = "";`

Comment: @isuru, can you please explain how this is different from my answer if you say you have `jQuery` included? I think you either have the jQuery included incorrectly or you don't include it at all. This answer is the same as mine only pure JavaScript way.

Comment: @Ionut As I think it should be jQuery version problem. I tried with your answer but it returns `Uncaught TypeError: control.val is not a function
    at HTMLImageElement.img.onload` error.

Comment: `document.getElementById("control").value = "";` there is a mistake in the answer '#' needs to be removed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `id` you already have set:

```js
var control = $("#mcontrol");
$("#clear").on("click", function() {
  control.val("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="mcontrol" />
<br>
<input type="file" id="mcontrol2" />
<button id="clear">Clear</button>
```

Comment: This seems correct but it's not working in my script.

Comment: @isuru, do you have `jQuery` library included?

Comment: Yes. My JQuery version is v1.11.3. I think it is the issue.

Comment: @isuru, that shouldn't be the problem. I've made a fiddle just to check https://jsfiddle.net/y3rvmLx9/ and it works. Somewhere else should be the problem.

Comment: Yes it should be worked. I cannot find the issue. However `document.getElementById("#mcontrol").value = "";` solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
// For first file feild 
$("#clear").on("click", function () {

    $('#mcontrol1').val("");
});

// For second file feild 
$("#clear").on("click", function () {

    $('#mcontrol2').val("");
});
```

Comment: Please try to provide context with your answer.  A standalone answer may solve a problem in this specific scenario, but an explanation may solve many future problems.  Try to include what you think is causing the issue and why your answer will solve it.