# In Javascript prompt yes/no before dropping the file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

Input file already have a value and
When user drop a file to `input[type=file]` I want to show a prompt with yes or no. 

if yes it will add file.
if no it will do no action and keep old value

```
$('input[type=file]').on('drop', function (e){
    if( !confirm("are you sure?") ){
    }
});
```

Comment: just return early in whatever drop handler you're using.

Comment: when a confirm popup opens i lost drop file data

Comment: In Firefox the input  shows "no file selected" after a confirm dialog, but selects a dropped file if `confirm` is not called.  Is file content being read locally, say for AJAX upload or is it simply uploaded as part of a form? Can you change page layout a little?

Comment: all solutions are welcome without ajax

Answer (score -1):

Use `return false` or `e.preventDefault();` to disable the default action:

```js
$('input[type=file]').on('drop', function(e) {
  if (!confirm("are you sure?")) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="test">
```

Unfortunately, this is apparently not portable. It works in Chrome and Safari, but not FireFox (I'm on a Mac and haven't tried IE).

A portable solution would have to use an HTML modal dialogue to get the confirmation. The cancellation callback can then use the technique in [Clearing <input type='file' /> using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery) to remove the dropped file from the input.

Comment: when you drop a file and press yes if it's not added, i am using firefox

Comment: You're right, it doesn't work in FF. I guess you'll need to implement an HTML modal prompt instead of using `confirm()`. Since the HTML prompt is asynchronous, you can't use `if()`. The callback will need to remove the file if the user says No. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery for how to do this.

Comment: i want to keep last selected file, and when user choose another file then ask prompt to replace with new file or not

Comment: I think that may be impossible.