# Remove input type file in IE10 not works

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

This was discussed a lot, but all of these solutions not work:

```
$("#getFile").val('');
```

Nor this:
    document.getElementById("getFile").value = "";

When console.log after using one of this - it prints the value of last file attached.
Also cloning not works, although remove the input value.

I want to trigger the event "change" when the user uses the same file after removing. The problem is thatthe value of the input is the last file uploaded.

Comment: You specifically mentioned IE10 - does it work in other browsers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clearing <input type='file' /> using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

why not just track the value with another variable and do an if statement? Like `var lastUpload = document.getElementById("getFile").value;`

then

```
addEventListener("change", function() {
  if(lastUpload === document.getElementById("getFile").value) {
    ...
  }
);
```

Comment: It still not work because the file input not "changes"

Comment: why not just do @EyalSegal

  `addEventListener("click", function() {
     document.getElementById("getFile").value = "";
    });`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is only possible if you can reset the form as well, see below:

```
 <form action="#" id="form">
     <label>Choose File: </label> <input type="file" name="getFile" id="getFile" /><br />
     <button type="button" onClick="removeFileName()">Clear File</button>
 </form>
```

And JS:

```
function removeFileName(){
    form.reset();
    var field = document.getElementById("getFile");
    console.log(field.value);
}
```

Comment: yes! thank you!
(but also using "click" event instead, or - although this is not necessary - use settimeout)