# Using Multiple file inputs to set background image of multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**What I'm trying to do:**

1 - How can I use a second file input to set the background image of a class of divs, in this case the **class .logo**? (currently, I have one file input, which is setting the background image for the **class .background**, but I need to add a second file input)

2 - How can I include a link that will "delete" or "trash" the file selected via the file input in order to reset a class of divs as having no background image?

**Here is how I've tried to work through this problem so far:**

I tried to add a second button, and duplicate the JS and then change the class names, however this broke everything. So I've provided two buttons for the file inputs here. Also, I tried to search for how to delete a file input once uploaded, but I could not understand anything I found. I read through [this question about clearing a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery), but I could not successfully apply what was described.

**Here's what I've tried so far:**

```js
$('.verborgen_file').hide();
$('.uploadButton').on('click', function() {
  $('.verborgen_file').click();
});

$('.verborgen_file').change(function() {
  var file = this.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function() {
    $('.background').css('background-image', 'url("' + reader.result + '")');
  }
  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  } else {}
});
```

```css
.background {
  background-image: url("");
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0px dashed #ddd;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  padding: 10px;
}

.background:hover {
  cursor: move;
}

div.bg-img {
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.responsive {
  background-image: url("");
  background-size: 120%;
  background-position: center;
  min-height: 20vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
}

.medium {
  background-image: url("");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.logo {
  height: 50px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputSection">
<h1>Input Section</h1>
Background:
<input type='file' class='verborgen_file' />
<input type="button" value="Upload" class="uploadButton" />
<a href="">delete</a>
<br> Logo:
<input type="button" value="Upload" class="uploadButton" /><a href="">delete</a>
</div>

<br>
<div class="imageSection">
<h1>Divs with Images Section</h1>
<div class="background responsive bg-img">
  <div class="logo">
  </div>

</div>

<div class="background medium bg-img">
  <div class="logo">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You haven't defined what the specific problem or question is as outlined in [ask]

Comment: I've edited the original question. Does this look better? Do you have any knowledge about how to help with what I'm trying to figure out?

Comment: Can anybody tell me if I've asked this question properly?

Comment: Well, you have described what you attempt to do but not the problems you faced when you were trying.

Comment: I've updated the question to include a description of how I've tried to work through this problem so far, and the obstacles I've faced. Do you have any knowledge of how to help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Am I still doing something wrong in the way that I'm asking the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, I would suggest to put the files that being selected by input in an array for further works.

But in your case, it would be simple. (However, the HTML structure makes this problem a little more complex.)

I added some `input` in HTML and added some data-attribute to `<input>` and `<a>`.

And, see comments below...

Edit: Since you separated them and put into another `div`, the `parent()` would be that `div`. Our goal is looking for the `div` contains both `inputSection` and `imageSection`, so replace `parent()` with `parents('.container')`. That's it!

```js
$('.verborgen_file').hide();

$('.uploadButton').on('click', function() {
  // find relative input and trigger click event
  var id = $(this).data('id')
  var target = $(this).siblings('input[data-id=' + id + ']')
  target.click();
});

$('.verborgen_file').change(function() {
  var $this = $(this)
  var file = this.files[0];
  var id = $(this).data('id')

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    // find either .background or .logo class in container and change the image
    $('body').find('div[data-id='+ id +']').css('background-image', 'url("' + reader.result + '")');
  }
  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  } else {
    // if file doesn't exist, clear the image
    $('body').find('div[data-id='+ id +']').css('background-image', '');
  }
});

$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var $this = $(this)
  var id = $this.data('id')
  var inputID = $this.siblings('input[data-id=' + id + ']').attr('id')
  // clear the relative input and trigger change event
  $('#' + inputID).val('').trigger('change')
})
```

```css
.background {
  background-image: url("");
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0px dashed #ddd;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  padding: 10px;
}

.background:hover {
  cursor: move;
}

div.bg-img {
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.responsive {
  background-image: url("");
  background-size: 120%;
  background-position: center;
  min-height: 20vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
}

.medium {
  background-image: url("");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.logo {
  height: 50px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Input Section</h1>
  <div class="inputSection">
    Background:
    <input id="bgInput1" type='file' class='verborgen_file' data-id="background1" />
    <input type="button" value="Upload" class="uploadButton" data-id="background1" />
    <a href="" data-id="background1">delete</a>
    <br> Logo:
    <input id="logoInput1" type='file' class='verborgen_file' data-id="logo1" />
    <input type="button" value="Upload" class="uploadButton" data-id="logo1" />
    <a href="" data-id="logo1">delete</a>
  </div>

  <br>
  <div class="imageSection">
    <h1>Divs with Images Section</h1>
    <div class="background responsive bg-img" data-id="background1">
      <div class="logo" data-id="logo1">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="background medium bg-img" data-id="background1">
      <div class="logo" data-id="logo1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Input Section</h1>
  <div class="inputSection">
    Background:
    <input id="bgInput2" type='file' class='verborgen_file' data-id="background2" />
    <input type="button" value="Upload" class="uploadButton" data-id="background2" />
    <a href="" data-id="background2">delete</a>
    <br> Logo:
    <input id="logoInput2" type='file' class='verborgen_file' data-id="logo2" />
    <input type="button" value="Upload" class="uploadButton" data-id="logo2" />
    <a href="" data-id="logo2">delete</a>
  </div>

  <br>
  <div class="imageSection">
    <h1>Divs with Images Section</h1>
    <div class="background responsive bg-img" data-id="background2">
      <div class="logo" data-id="logo2">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="background medium bg-img" data-id="background2">
      <div class="logo" data-id="logo2">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh! ok, this still breaks. I think the issue is the top level div class of .container. Is there a way for the inputs to be placed in any other div and still function as they do now, where the image-background divs are in any other div on a given page?

Comment: This is not a good way since you have to set `data-id` attribute everywhere but works in the situation you mentioned.

Comment: Ok, let me redo the html so it reflects what I'm really trying to do. Give me a minute.

Comment: please see this codepen: https://codepen.io/db13/pen/ce3e54a83dc0ef6717320e2dea80842b

Comment: I'm not sure if its my HTML structure, or maybe some other existing JS that is breaking everything.

Comment: I've searched and searched for how to solve this, but I cannot understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: do you think it has to do with my HTML structure? or is there anything more you can tell me about the 'data-id' issue?

Comment: You have to add `data-id` attribute at anywhere you want to display the image. Like `<div class="background responsive bg-img" data-id="background1">` and `<div class="logo" data-id="logo1"></div>`.