# Hide / show depending on input type=file value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

It works fine when I select / deselect a file via the Choose File button:

```js
$("input[type='submit']").toggle(false);

$("input[type='file']").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() != "") {
    $("#btn").toggle();
  } else {
    $("#btn").toggle();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="fld" type="file" name="image" id="file">

<input id="btn" type="submit" value="Upload / Edit picture" name="upload_picture" id="upload_picture" class="btn" />
<br>
<br>
<div id="remove_button">Remove</div>
```

Click on the Choose File button and select a file. The Upload / Edit picture button will appear. Now click on the Choose File button again but do not select a file and exit the small popup window. The Upload / Edit picture button will disappear.

In my case I want the input="file" value to be cleared and the Upload / Edit picture button to disappear if I clear the value by clicking on the `<div id="remove_button">Remove</div>`

Is there a way to do that?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e0o8stvp/1/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clearing <input type='file' /> using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code into your javascript

```
$("#btn").toggle(false);

$("#fld").change(function(){

if($(this).val() != "")
{
 $("#btn").toggle();
} 
else{
 $("#btn").toggle();
}
});

$("#remove_button").click(function(){
  $("#fld").val('');
  document.getElementById("btn").style.visibility = "hidden";
})
```

and remove id tag from your html..it has two ids for the button
change it like

```
<input id="btn" type="submit" value="Upload / Edit picture" name="upload_picture" 
class="btn" />
```

Comment: I chose this one because it's the closest to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to bind a click event listener to the `#remove_button` element (which I recommend that you should be using `<button>` instead of a `<div>`).

In the callback, you can simply set the value of the file input to an empty string, which effectively resets the field. Remember that you will need to use `.trigger('change')` to manually reinvoke the show/hide logic based on the file input value:

```js
const $submit = $("input[type='submit']");
$submit.hide();

$("#fld").change(function() {
  $submit.toggle(!!this.value);
});

$('#remove_button').click(function() {
  $('#fld').val('').trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="fld" type="file" name="image" id="file">

<input id="btn" type="submit" value="Upload / Edit picture" name="upload_picture" id="upload_picture" class="btn" />
<br>
<br>
<button id="remove_button">Remove</button>
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for catching that! I was a bit hasty at posting my answer: updated it now :)