# Angularjs directive File upload not clearing up

Tags: angularjs, file-upload

I have made a directive for file upload... I am trying to clear the file upload attachment using external button.

[my plunkr work](http://plnkr.co/edit/oYjIbdI9zUKoZXXlRaZC?)

I am able to clear the scope model with the button, but however the input field itself is not acting up on the clear event. (i.e the message like "2 files" still remains there).

Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is that you need to clear the contents of the file input element - but that's not so easy. [See this answer for one way to do it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/832730/238427)

Comment: @JoseM thanks.. Post your comment as answer.. I will accept it